# Loop inside React JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to do something like the following in React JSX (where ObjectRow is a separate component):

```
<tbody>
    for (var i=0; i < numrows; i++) {
        <ObjectRow/>
    } 
</tbody>
```

I realize and understand why this isn't valid JSX, since JSX maps to function calls. However, coming from template land and being new to JSX, I am unsure how I would achieve the above (adding a component multiple times).

Comment: It's important to note that in JSX you need the { } tags around your JavaScript Syntax. This may help https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#child-expressions.

Comment: `let todos = this.props.todos.map((todo) => {return <h1>{todo.title}</h1>})`

Comment: @OverCoder why would you put whole return into {} tag it would be => return <h1>{todo.title}</h1> Isn't it ?

Comment: @pravinpoudel actually that answer is old, more like `let todos = this.props.todos.map(t => <h1>{t.title}</h1>)` :)

Comment: The "for" doesn't return a value, you need to return an array element for JSX in your example.

Comment: You can put any Javascript expression, _any valid unit of code that resolves to a value_,  inside jsx curly braces.  A typical for loop is not a javascript expression because it does not resolve to value. [expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#expressions)

Comment: A great way to think about this is the return value of a `for loop`. A `for loop` doesn't really return anything, which is why we have to push values into an array and return the array. If you're looking for more explanation, checkout [How To Loop Inside React JSX - React FAQ](https://victorofoegbu.com/notes/loop-inside-react-jsx-faq)

Comment: Can anyone please tell me why is this an invalid JSX?

Comment: you could try something like {numrows.map(numrow => <ObjectRow key={numrow}/>)}

the key is there to silence a react warning

Comment: This comment can be improved.

Answer (score 1786, accepted):

Think of it like you're just calling JavaScript functions. You can't use a `for` loop where the arguments to a function call would go:

```
return tbody(
    for (let i = 0; i < numrows; i++) {
        ObjectRow()
    } 
)
```

See how the function `tbody` is being passed a `for` loop as an argument – leading to a syntax error.

But you can make an array, and then pass that in as an argument:

```
const rows = [];
for (let i = 0; i < numrows; i++) {
    rows.push(ObjectRow());
}
return tbody(rows);
```

---

You can basically use the same structure when working with JSX:

```
const rows = [];
for (let i = 0; i < numrows; i++) {
    // note: we are adding a key prop here to allow react to uniquely identify each
    // element in this array. see: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html
    rows.push(<ObjectRow key={i} />);
}
return <tbody>{rows}</tbody>;
```

Incidentally, my JavaScript example is almost exactly what that example of JSX transforms into. Play around with [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl) to get a feel for how JSX works.

Comment: Verbose for just a for loop. All you need is `Array.from({ length: numrows }).map((it, index) => <ObjectRow key={} />)`

Answer (score 1170):

I am not sure if this will work for your situation, but often [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a good answer.

If this was your code with the *for* loop:

```
<tbody>
    for (var i=0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        <ObjectRow obj={objects[i]} key={i}>
    }
</tbody>
```

You could write it like this with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
<tbody>
    {objects.map(function(object, i){
        return <ObjectRow obj={object} key={i} />;
    })}
</tbody>
```

ES6 syntax:

```
<tbody>
    {objects.map((object, i) => <ObjectRow obj={object} key={i} />)}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Map makes more sense if the iteratee is an array; A for loop is appropriate if it is a number.

Comment: `<tbody>{objects.map((o, i) => <ObjectRow obj={o} key={i}/>}</tbody>` using Reactify's ES6 support or Babel.

Comment: If you have multiple lines of JSX you're returning, use parenthesis around all of the lines, i.e. `return ( ... your lines here ... )`

Comment: Don't use the index as a key if the nested component has a delete event.

Answer (score 740):

If you don't already have an array to `map()` like @FakeRainBrigand's answer, and want to inline this so the source layout corresponds to the output closer than @SophieAlpert's answer:

## With ES2015 (ES6) syntax (spread and arrow functions)

http://plnkr.co/edit/mfqFWODVy8dKQQOkIEGV?p=preview

```js
<tbody>
  {[...Array(10)].map((x, i) =>
    <ObjectRow key={i} />
  )}
</tbody>
```

Re: transpiling with Babel, its [caveats page](https://babeljs.io/docs/advanced/caveats/) says that `Array.from` is required for spread, but at present (`v5.8.23`) that does not seem to be the case when spreading an actual `Array`. I have a [documentation issue](https://github.com/babel/babel.github.io/pull/392) open to clarify that. But use at your own risk or polyfill.

## Vanilla ES5

### `Array.apply`

```
<tbody>
  {Array.apply(0, Array(10)).map(function (x, i) {
    return <ObjectRow key={i} />;
  })}
</tbody>
```

### Inline IIFE

http://plnkr.co/edit/4kQjdTzd4w69g8Suu2hT?p=preview

```js
<tbody>
  {(function (rows, i, len) {
    while (++i <= len) {
      rows.push(<ObjectRow key={i} />)
    }
    return rows;
  })([], 0, 10)}
</tbody>
```

### Combination of techniques from other answers

Keep the source layout corresponding to the output, but make the inlined part more compact:

```js
render: function () {
  var rows = [], i = 0, len = 10;
  while (++i <= len) rows.push(i);

  return (
    <tbody>
      {rows.map(function (i) {
        return <ObjectRow key={i} index={i} />;
      })}
    </tbody>
  );
}
```

## With ES2015 syntax & `Array` methods

With `Array.prototype.fill` you could do this as an alternative to using spread as illustrated above:

```js
<tbody>
  {Array(10).fill(1).map((el, i) =>
    <ObjectRow key={i} />
  )}
</tbody>
```

(I think you could actually omit any argument to `fill()`, but I'm not 100% on that.) Thanks to @FakeRainBrigand for correcting my mistake in an earlier version of the `fill()` solution (see revisions).

## `key`

In all cases the `key` attr alleviates a warning with the development build, but isn't accessible in the child. You can pass an extra attr if you want the index available in the child. See [Lists and Keys](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html) for discussion.

Comment: Please don't make an array just to iterate from 0..N. That's peak Javascript.

Answer (score 139):

Simply using **map** *Array* method with ES6 syntax:

```
<tbody>
  {items.map(item => <ObjectRow key={item.id} name={item.name} />)} 
</tbody>
```

Don't forget the `key` property.

Answer (score 115):

Using the **Array map** function is a very common way to loop through an **Array** of elements and create components according to them in **React**. This is a great way to do a loop which is a pretty efficient and is a tidy way to do your loops in **JSX**. It's **not** the only way to do it, but the **preferred way.**

Also, don't forget having a **unique Key** for each iteration as required. The **map function** creates a unique index from 0, but it's not recommended using the produced index, but if your value is unique or if there is a unique key, you can use them:

```
<tbody>
  {numrows.map(x=> <ObjectRow key={x.id} />)}
</tbody>
```

Also, a few lines from **MDN** if you not familiar with the map function on Array:

> map calls a provided callback function once for each element in an
> array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results. callback
> is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values,
> including undefined. It is not called for missing elements of the
> array (that is, indexes that have never been set, which have been
> deleted or which have never been assigned a value).
>
> callback is invoked with three arguments: the value of the element,
> the index of the element, and the Array object being traversed.
>
> If a thisArg parameter is provided to the map, it will be used as
> callback's this value. Otherwise, the value undefined will be used as
> its this value. This value ultimately observable by the callback is
> determined according to the usual rules for determining the this seen
> by a function.
>
> map does not mutate the array on which it is called (although
> callback, if invoked, may do so).

Comment: `Array#map` is not async!

Answer (score 89):

If you're already using `lodash`, the [`_.times`](https://lodash.com/docs#times) function is handy.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Select from "./Select";
import _ from "lodash";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <ol>
          {_.times(3, (i) => (
            <li key={i}>repeated 3 times</li>
          ))}
        </ol>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Only import ```times``` from Lodash, not the entire library. It's okay during development to avoid backwards incompatibility as Lodash releases updates, but in production you're costing seconds importing an entire library.

Comment: @coder9833idls Might need to switch to `lodash-es` for tree-shaking to work, no?

Answer (score 84):

There are multiple ways to go about doing this. JSX eventually gets compiled to JavaScript, so as long as you're writing valid JavaScript, you'll be good.

My answer aims to consolidate all the wonderful ways already presented here:

**If you do not have an array of object, simply the number of rows:**

Within the `return` block, creating an `Array` and using `Array.prototype.map`:

```
render() {
  return (
    <tbody>
      {Array(numrows).fill(null).map((value, index) => (
        <ObjectRow key={index}>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  );
}
```

Outside the `return` block, simply use a normal JavaScript *for* loop:

```
render() {
  let rows = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numrows; i++) {
    rows.push(<ObjectRow key={i}/>);
  }
  return (
    <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
  );
}
```

Immediately invoked function expression:

```
render() {
  return (
    <tbody>
      {(() => {
        let rows = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < numrows; i++) {
          rows.push(<ObjectRow key={i}/>);
        }
        return rows;
      })()}
    </tbody>
  );
}
```

**If you have an array of objects**

Within the `return` block, `.map()` each object to a `<ObjectRow>` component:

```
render() {
  return (
    <tbody>
      {objectRows.map((row, index) => (
        <ObjectRow key={index} data={row} />
      ))}
    </tbody>
  );
}
```

Outside the `return` block, simply use a normal JavaScript *for* loop:

```
render() {
  let rows = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < objectRows.length; i++) {
    rows.push(<ObjectRow key={i} data={objectRows[i]} />);
  }
  return (
    <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
  );
}
```

Immediately invoked function expression:

```
render() {
  return (
    <tbody>
      {(() => {
        const rows = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < objectRows.length; i++) {
          rows.push(<ObjectRow key={i} data={objectRows[i]} />);
        }
        return rows;
      })()}
    </tbody>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 57):

You can also extract outside the return block:

```
render: function() {
    var rows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < numrows; i++) {
        rows.push(<ObjectRow key={i}/>);
    } 

    return (<tbody>{rows}</tbody>);
}
```

Answer (score 48):

You might want to checkout [React Templates](http://wix.github.io/react-templates/), which does let you use JSX-style templates in React, with a few directives (such as rt-repeat).

Your example, if you used react-templates, would be:

```
<tbody>
     <ObjectRow rt-repeat="obj in objects"/>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 47):

If you opt to convert this inside **return()** of the **render** method, the easiest option would be using the **map( )** method. Map your array into JSX syntax using the map() function, as shown below (*ES6 syntax is used*).

---

**Inside the parent component**:

```html
<tbody>
   { objectArray.map(object => <ObjectRow key={object.id} object={object.value} />) }
</tbody>
```

Please note the `key` attribute is added to your child component. If you didn't provide a key attribute, you can see the following warning on your console.

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have
> a unique "key" prop.

**Note:** One common mistake people do is using `index` as the key when iterating. Using `index` of the element as a key is an antipattern, and you can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318). In short, if it's **not** a static list, never use `index` as the key.

---

Now at the **ObjectRow** component, you can access the object from its properties.

**Inside the ObjectRow component**

```
const { object } = this.props
```

Or

```
const object = this.props.object
```

This should fetch you the object you passed from the parent component to the variable `object` in the **ObjectRow** component. Now you can spit out the values in that object according to your purpose.

---

References:

[map() method in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[ECMAScript 6 or ES6](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#readme)

Comment: This worked for me, but I added "/" to end the "<ObjectRow />" tag.

Answer (score 39):

If *numrows* is an array, it's very simple:

```
<tbody>
   {numrows.map(item => <ObjectRow />)}
</tbody>
```

The array data type in React is much better. An array can back a new array, and support filter, reduce, etc.

Answer (score 34):

This can be done in multiple ways.

1. As suggested above, before `return` store all elements in the array
2. Loop inside `return`

   **Method 1:**

   ```
   let container = [];
   let arr = [1, 2, 3] //can be anything array, object
   arr.forEach((val, index) => {
     container.push(
     <div key={index}>
       val
     </div>)
     /**
     * 1. All loop generated elements require a key
     * 2. only one parent element can be placed in Array
     * e.g. container.push(
     *         <div key={index}>
                 val
               </div>
               <div>
               this will throw error
               </div>
           )
     **/
   });
   return (
     <div>
       <div>any things goes here</div>
       <div>{container}</div>
     </div>
   )
   ```

   **Method 2:**

   ```
   return (
     <div>
       <div>any things goes here</div>
       <div>
         {
           (() => {
             let container = [];
             let arr = [1, 2, 3] //can be anything array, object
             arr.forEach((val, index) => {
               container.push(
                 <div key={index}>
                   val
                 </div>)
             });
             return container;
           })()
         }
       </div>
     </div>
   )
   ```

Comment: Yeah. In my current project, I use method 1, i.e using Array.prototype,forEach() method to create HTML select element which is populated by data from database. However, I will more likely replace them with Array.prototype.map() method, as the map method looks more compact (less code).

Answer (score 33):

There are several answers pointing to using the `map` statement. Here is a complete example using an iterator within the **FeatureList** component to list **Feature** components based on a JSON data structure called **features**.

```
const FeatureList = ({ features, onClickFeature, onClickLikes }) => (
  <div className="feature-list">
    {features.map(feature =>
      <Feature
        key={feature.id}
        {...feature}
        onClickFeature={() => onClickFeature(feature.id)}
        onClickLikes={() => onClickLikes(feature.id)}
      />
    )}
  </div>
);
```

You can view the complete [FeatureList code](https://github.com/manavsehgal/reactspeedcoding/blob/master/app/components/Roadmap/FeatureList.jsx) on GitHub. The [features fixture is listed here](https://github.com/manavsehgal/reactspeedcoding/blob/master/app/fixtures/roadmap/features.js).

Comment: When dealing with JSON data, such when retrieving data from database using fetch API, I rely on using Array.prototype.map method. It is a convenient and proven way for that purpose.

Answer (score 32):

Let us say we have an array of items in your state:

```
[{name: "item1", id: 1}, {name: "item2", id: 2}, {name: "item3", id: 3}]

<tbody>
    {this.state.items.map((item) => {
        <ObjectRow key={item.id} name={item.name} />
    })}
</tbody>
```

Comment: I think you may need to get rid of the {} after the map(item), that seemed to work them for me.

Comment: Just a thought: ```{this.state.items?.map((item) => ```, or my favourite syntax stalwart: ```{this.state.items && this.state.items.map((item) =>``` and drop the unnecessary () from ```(item)``` since there is only one parameter. You're going to get frustrated rendering the component asynchronously and not having the local state imported yet.

Comment: In this case, it will not render any thing. you need to add `return` keyword inside your `{}` or need to remove the `{}`.
`{this.state.items.map((item) => {return(<ObjectRow key={item.id} name={item.name}/>)})}` or 
`{this.state.items.map((item) =>(<ObjectRow key={item.id} name={item.name} />))}`

Answer (score 32):

To loop for a number of times and return, you can achieve it with the help of [`from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
<tbody>
  {
    Array.from(Array(i)).map(() => <ObjectRow />)
  }
</tbody>
```

where `i = number of times`

---

If you want to assign unique key IDs into the rendered components, you can use `React.Children.toArray` as proposed in the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrentoarray)

**React.Children.toArray**

Returns the children opaque data structure as a flat array with keys assigned to each child. Useful if you want to manipulate collections of children in your render methods, especially if you want to reorder or slice this.props.children before passing it down.

> **Note:**
>
> `React.Children.toArray()` changes keys to preserve the semantics of nested arrays when flattening lists of children. That is, toArray prefixes each key in the returned array so that each element’s key is scoped to the input array containing it.

```
<tbody>
  {
    React.Children.toArray(
      Array.from(Array(i)).map(() => <ObjectRow />)
    )
  }
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 29):

An ECMAScript 2015 / [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)) possibility is using a generator function to create an array of JSX:

```
function* jsxLoop(times, callback)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < times; ++i)
        yield callback(i);
}

...

<tbody>
    {[...jsxLoop(numrows, i =>
        <ObjectRow key={i}/>
    )]}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 24):

## ES2015 **Array.from** with the map function + key

If you have nothing to `.map()` you can use `Array.from()` with the `map` function to repeat elements:

```
<tbody>
  {Array.from({ length: 5 }, (value, key) => <ObjectRow key={key} />)}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 21):

...Or you can also prepare an array of objects and map it to a function to have the desired output. I prefer this, because it helps me to maintain the good practice of coding with no logic inside the return of render.

```
render() {
const mapItem = [];
for(let i =0;i<item.length;i++) 
  mapItem.push(i);
const singleItem => (item, index) {
 // item the single item in the array 
 // the index of the item in the array
 // can implement any logic here
 return (
  <ObjectRow/>
)

}
  return(
   <tbody>{mapItem.map(singleItem)}</tbody>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 21):

I use this:

```
gridItems = this.state.applications.map(app =>
          <ApplicationItem key={app.Id} app={app } />
);
```

**PS: never forget the key or you will have a lot of warnings!**

Comment: Or use the array index if your items don't have an `.Id` property, like `items.map( (item, index) => <Foo key={index}>{item}</Foo>`

Answer (score 19):

Here's a simple solution to it.

```js
var Object_rows = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numrows; i++) {
  Object_rows.push(<ObjectRow />);
}
<tbody>{Object_rows}</tbody>;
```

No mapping and complex code is required. You just need to push the rows to the array and return the values to render it.

Comment: When creating html select element, this similar technique was the one that came to my mind firstly, So I used it, although I use the forEach() method. But when I reread the React doc on topics of Lists and Keys, I found that they use the map() method as also shown by several answers here. This makes me think that it is the preferred way. I agree, since it looks more compact (less code).

Answer (score 18):

You can of course solve with a .map as suggested by the other answer. If you already use [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)), you could think about using [jsx-control-statements](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsx-control-statements).

They require a little of setting, but I think it's worth in terms of readability (especially for non-React developer).
If you use a linter, there's also [eslint-plugin-jsx-control-statements](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jsx-control-statements).

Answer (score 18):

Simply use `.map()` to loop through your collection and return `<ObjectRow>` items with props from each iteration.

Assuming `objects` is an array somewhere...

```
<tbody>
  { objects.map((obj, index) => <ObjectRow obj={ obj } key={ index }/> ) }
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 17):

Your JSX code will compile into pure JavaScript code, any tags will be replaced by `ReactElement` objects. In JavaScript, you cannot call a function multiple times to collect their returned variables.

It is illegal, the only way is to use an array to store the function returned variables.

Or you can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which is available [since JavaScript ES5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Specifications) to handle this situation.

Maybe we can write other compiler to recreate a new JSX syntax to implement a repeat function just like [Angular's `ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Answer (score 16):

I tend to favor an approach where programming logic happens outside the return value of `render`.  This helps keep what is actually rendered easy to grok.

So I'd probably do something like:

```
import _ from 'lodash';

...

const TableBody = ({ objects }) => {
  const objectRows = objects.map(obj => <ObjectRow object={obj} />);      

  return <tbody>{objectRows}</tbody>;
}
```

Admittedly this is such a small amount of code that inlining it might work fine.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a sample from the React documentation, [JavaScript Expressions as Children](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#javascript-expressions-as-children):

```
function Item(props) {
  return <li>{props.message}</li>;
}

function TodoList() {
  const todos = ['finish doc', 'submit pr', 'nag dan to review'];
  return (
    <ul>
      {todos.map((message) => <Item key={message} message={message} />)}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

As for your case, I suggest writing like this:

```
function render() {
  return (
    <tbody>
      {numrows.map((roe, index) => <ObjectRow key={index} />)}
    </tbody>
  );
}
```

Please notice the *key* is very important, because React use the *key* to differ data in array.

Comment: Is it possible to map over a number? I tried it in console and it didn't work.

Answer (score 15):

You may use .map() in a React *for* loop.

```html
<tbody>
    { newArray.map(() => <ObjectRow />) }
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 13):

Since you are writing JavaScript syntax inside JSX code, you need to wrap your JavaScript code in curly braces.

```
row = () => {
   var rows = [];
   for (let i = 0; i<numrows; i++) {
       rows.push(<ObjectRow/>);
   }
   return rows;
}
<tbody>
{this.row()}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 12):

With time, the language is becoming more mature, and we often stumble upon common problems like this. The problem is to loop a Component 'n' times.

```
{[...new Array(n)].map((item, index) => <MyComponent key={index} />)}
```

where, n -is the number of times you want to loop. `item` will be undefined and `index` will be as usual. Also, [ESLint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESLint) discourages using an array index as key.

But you have the advantage of not requiring to initialize the array before and most importantly avoiding the `for` loop...

To avoid the inconvenience of item as undefined you can use an `_`, so that it will be ignored when linting and won't throw any linting error, such as

```
{[...new Array(n)].map((_, index) => <MyComponent key={index} />)}
```

Answer (score 12):

If you really want a *for* loop equivalent (you have a single number, not an array), just use [`range` from Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#range).

Don't reinvent the wheel and don't obfuscate your code. Just use the standard utility library.

```js
import range from 'lodash/range'

range(4);
// => [0, 1, 2, 3]

range(1, 5);
// => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 11):

I use it like

```
<tbody>
  { numrows ? (
     numrows.map(obj => { return <ObjectRow /> }) 
    ) : null
  }
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also use a self-invoking function:

```
return <tbody>
           {(() => {
              let row = []
              for (var i = 0; i < numrows; i++) {
                  row.push(<ObjectRow key={i} />)
              }
              return row

           })()}
        </tbody>
```

Comment: Using anonymous functions inside render is not considered a good practice in react, as these functions need to be re-created or discarded on each re-render.

Comment: @VlatkoVlahek you're mistaking it with function props being re-created each render cycle, which _could_ lead to poorer performance on a large scale. Creating anonymous function anywhere else is not going to affect performance in any significant way.

Comment: @EmileBergeron This was a while ago haha. I do agree if this is not used as a prop, there is no difference.

Answer (score 9):

When I want to add a certain number of components, I use a helper function.

Define a function that returns JSX:

```
const myExample = () => {
    let myArray = []
    for(let i = 0; i<5;i++) {
        myArray.push(<MyComponent/>)
    }
    return myArray
}

//... in JSX

<tbody>
    {myExample()}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 9):

Even this piece of code does the same job.

```
<tbody>
   {array.map(i => 
      <ObjectRow key={i.id} name={i.name} />
   )}
</tbody>
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 9):

*[Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)* is the best way. If you want to create an array of JSX with some length.

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <tbody>
      {Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, key) => (
        <ObjectRow {...{ key }} />
      ))}
    </tbody>
  );
}
```

The above example is for when you do not have an array, so if you have an array you should map it in JSX like this:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <tbody>
      {list.map((item, key) => (
        <ObjectRow {...{ key }} />
      ))}
    </tbody>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do something like:

```
let foo = [1,undefined,3]
{ foo.map(e => !!e ? <Object /> : null )}
```

Answer (score 8):

A loop inside JSX is very simple. Try this:

```
return this.state.data.map((item, index) => (
  <ComponentName key={index} data={item} />
));
```

Answer (score 8):

If you need JavaScript code inside your JSX, you add `{ }` and then write your JavaScript code inside these brackets.
It is just that simple.

And the same way you can loop inside JSX/react.

Say:

```
<tbody>
    {`your piece of code in JavaScript` }
</tbody>
```

Example:

```
<tbody>
    { items.map((item, index) => {
        console.log(item)}) ; // Print item
        return <span>{index}</span>;
    } // Looping using map()
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 8):

Below are possible solutions that you can do in React in terms of iterating array of objects or plain array

```
const rows = [];
const numrows = [{"id" : 01, "name" : "abc"}];
numrows.map((data, i) => {
    rows.push(<ObjectRow key={data.id} name={data.name}/>);
});

<tbody>
    { rows }
</tbody>
```

*Or*

```
const rows = [];
const numrows = [1,2,3,4,5];
for(let i=1, i <= numrows.length; i++){
    rows.push(<ObjectRow key={numrows[i]} />);
};

<tbody>
    { rows }
</tbody>
```

An even more better approach I became familiar with recent days for iterating an array of objects is `.map` directly in the render with return or without return:

#### *.map* with return

```
 const numrows = [{"id" : 01, "name" : "abc"}];
 <tbody>
     {numrows.map(data=> {
         return <ObjectRow key={data.id} name={data.name}/>
     })}
</tbody>
```

#### *.map* without return

```
 const numrows = [{"id" : 01, "name" : "abc"}];
 <tbody>
     {numrows.map(data=> (
         <ObjectRow key={data.id} name={data.name}/>
     ))}
</tbody>
```

Comment: rows should be `let`

Comment: @toing_toing Rows no need to be let unless you want to override them

Answer (score 7):

React elements are simple JavaScript, so you can follow the rule of JavaScript. You can use a `for` loop in JavaScript like this:-

```
<tbody>
    for (var i=0; i < numrows; i++) {
        <ObjectRow/>
    } 
</tbody>
```

But the valid and best way is to use the `.map` function. Shown below:-

```
<tbody>
    {listObject.map(function(listObject, i){
        return <ObjectRow key={i} />;
    })}
</tbody>
```

Here, one thing is necessary: to define the key. Otherwise it will throw a warning like this:-

> Warning.js:36 Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have
> a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `ComponentName`. See
> "link" for more information.

Answer (score 7):

For printing an array value if you don't have the key value par, then use the below code -

```
<div>
    {my_arr.map(item => <div>{item} </div> )}                    
</div>
```

Comment: Don't forget about the `key` prop.

Answer (score 7):

You can try the new *for of* loop:

```
const apple = {
    color: 'red',
    size: 'medium',
    weight: 12,
    sugar: 10
}
for (const prop of apple.entries()){
    console.log(prop);
}
```

Here's [a few examples](http://%20https://flaviocopes.com/react-how-to-loop/):

Answer (score 7):

Unless you declare a function and enclose it with parameters, it is not possible. In a JSXExpression you can only write *expressions* and cannot write *statements* like a for(), declare variables or classes, or a if() statement.

That's why function CallExpressions are so in the mood today. My advice: get used to them. This is what I would do:

```
const names = ['foo', 'bar', 'seba']
const people = <ul>{names.map(name => <li>{name}</li>)}</ul>
```

Filtering:

```
const names = ['foo', undefined, 'seba']
const people = <ul>{names.filter(person => !!person).map(name => <li>{name}</li>)}</ul>
```

if():

```
var names = getNames()
const people = {names && names.length &&
   <ul>{names.map(name => <li>{name}</li>)}</ul> }
```

if - else:

```
var names = getNames()
const people = {names && names.length ?
  <ul>{names.map(name => <li>{name}</li>)}</ul> : <p>no results</p> }
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the map function.

```
<tbody> 
   {objects.map((object, i) =>  <ObjectRow obj={object} key={i} />)} 
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do the same directly in the JSX, using map instead of a for-of loop:

```
render: function() {
const items = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
 return (
  <ul>
     {items.map((value, index) => {
     return <li key={index}>{value}</li>
     })}
 </ul>
 )
}
```

Comment: How is this different from previous answers?

Answer (score 7):

Just do something like this:

```js
<tbody>
    {new Array(numRows).fill("", 0, numRows).map((p, i) => <YourRaw key={i} />)}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Does it actually run here? What is supposed to happen?

Comment: You should specify the numRows and the 'YourRaw' element

Answer (score 6):

Well, here you go.

```
{
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map((value, index) => {
        return <div key={index}>{value}</div>
    })
}
```

All you have to do is just map your array and return whatever you want to render. And please don't forget to use `key` in the returned element.

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
<tbody>
  {new Array(numrows).map((row,index)=><ObjectRow key={***someThingUniqe***}/>)} //don't use index as key 
</tbody>
```

if you wanna know why you shouldn't use indices as keys in react check  [this](https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/why-do-i-need-keys-in-react-lists/)

Answer (score 5):

```
return (
    <table>
       <tbody>
          {
            numrows.map((item, index) => {
              <ObjectRow data={item} key={index}>
            })
          }
       </tbody>
    </table>
);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This will break. You need to close the ObjectRow tag and you are supposed to return something in your map callback.

Answer (score 5):

You can use an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) if you really want to literally use a *for* loop inside JSX.

```
<tbody>
  {
    (function () {
      const view = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < numrows; i++) {
        view.push(<ObjectRow key={i}/>);
      }
      return view;
    }())
  }
</tbody>
```

Comment: If you want the this keyword to be equal to the class itself, then just transform the function to fat arrow.

Answer (score 5):

@jacefarm If I understand right you can use this code:

```
<tbody>
    { new Array(numrows).fill(<ObjectRow/>) } 
</tbody>
```

Either you can use this code:

```
<tbody>
   { new Array(numrows).fill('').map((item, ind) => <ObjectRow key={ind}/>) } 
</tbody>
```

And this:

```
<tbody>
    new Array(numrows).fill(ObjectRow).map((Item, ind) => <Item key={ind}/>)
</tbody>
```

Comment: What does "@jacefarm" refer to? A comment (where?)? An answer (where?)?

Answer (score 5):

Using *map* in React are best practices for iterating over an array.

To prevent some errors with [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015), the syntax map is used like this in React:

```
<tbody>
    {items.map((item, index) => <ObjectRow key={index} name={item.name} />)}
</tbody>
```

Here you call a Component, <ObjectRow/>, so you don't need to put parenthesis after the arrow.

But you can be make this too:

```
{items.map((item, index) => (
    <ObjectRow key={index} name={item.name} />
))}
```

Or:

```
{items.map((item, index) => {
    // Here you can log 'item'
    return (
        <ObjectRow key={index} name={item.name} />
    )
})}
```

I say that because if you put a bracket "{}" after the arrow React will not throw an error and will display a whitelist.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is you don't return any JSX element. There are another solutions for such cases, but I will provide the simplest one: "use the *map* function"!

```
<tbody>
  { numrows.map(item => <ObjectRow key={item.uniqueField} />) }
</tbody>
```

It's so simple and beautiful, isn't it?

Answer (score 5):

I've found one more solution to follow the map
render:

```
 <tbody>{this.getcontent()}</tbody>
```

And a *separate* function:

```
getcontent() {
    const bodyarea = this.state.movies.map(movies => (
        <tr key={movies._id}>
            <td>{movies.title}</td>
            <td>{movies.genre.name}</td>
            <td>{movies.numberInStock}</td>
            <td>{movies.publishDate}</td>
            <td>
                <button
                    onClick={this.deletMovie.bind(this, movies._id)}
                    className="btn btn-danger"
                >
                    Delete
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    ));
    return bodyarea;
}
```

This example solves many problems easily.

Answer (score 5):

Use `{}` around JavaScript code within a JSX block to get it to properly perform whatever JavaScript action you are trying to do.

```
<tr>
  <td>
    {data.map((item, index) => {
      {item}
    })}
  </td>
</tr>
```

This is kind of vague, but you can swap out data for any array.  This will give you a table row and table item for each item. If you have more than just one thing in each node of the array, you will want to target that specifically by doing something like this:

```
<td>{item.someProperty}</td>
```

In which case, you will want to surround it with a different `td` and arrange the previous example differently.

Answer (score 5):

There are many solutions posted out there in terms of iterating an array and generating JSX elements. All of them are good, but all of them used an index directly in a loop. We are recommended to use unique id from data as a key, but when we do not have a unique id from each object in the array we will use index as a key, but you are not recommended to use an index as a key directly.

One more thing why we go for *.map*, but why not .foEach because .map returns a new array. There are different ways of doing *.map* these days.

Below different versions of using .map illustrates in detail about how to use a unique key and how to use .map for looping JSX elements.

*.map* without return when returning single a JSX element and unique id from data as a key version:

```
const {objects} = this.state;

<tbody>
    {objects.map(object => <ObjectRow obj={object} key={object.id} />)}
</tbody>
```

*.map* without return when returning multiple JSX elements and unique id from data as a key version

```
const {objects} = this.state;

<tbody>
    {objects.map(object => (
        <div key={object.id}>
            <ObjectRow obj={object} />
        </div>
    ))}
</tbody>
```

*.map* without return when returning a single JSX element and index as a key version:

```
const {objects} = this.state;

<tbody>
    {objects.map((object, index) => <ObjectRow obj={object} key={`Key${index}`} />)}
</tbody>
```

*.map* without return when returning multiple JSX elements and index as a key version:

```
const {objects} = this.state;

<tbody>
    {objects.map((object, index) => (
        <div key={`Key${index}`}>
            <ObjectRow obj={object} />
        </div>
    ))}
</tbody>
```

*.map* with return when returning multiple JSX elements and index as a key version:

```
const {objects} = this.state;

<tbody>
    {objects.map((object, index) => {
        return (
            <div key={`Key${index}`}>
                <ObjectRow obj={object} />
            </div>
        )
    })}
</tbody>
```

*.map* with return when returning multiple JSX elements and unique id from data as a key version:

```
const {objects} = this.state;

<tbody>
    {objects.map(object => {
        return (
            <div key={object.id}>
                <ObjectRow obj={object} />
            </div>
        )
    })}
</tbody>
```

The other way is

```
render() {
  const {objects} = this.state;
  const objectItems = objects.map(object => {
       return (
           <div key={object.id}>
               <ObjectRow obj={object} />
           </div>
       )
  })
  return(
      <div>
          <tbody>
              {objectItems}
          </tbody>
      </div>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To provide a more straightforward solution in case you want to use a specific row count which is stored as `Integer`-value.

With the help of `typedArrays` we could achieve the desired solution in the following manner.

```
// Let's create a typedArray with length of `numrows`-value
const typedArray = new Int8Array(numrows); // typedArray.length is now 2
const rows = []; // Prepare rows-array
for (let arrKey in typedArray) { // Iterate keys of typedArray
  rows.push(<ObjectRow key={arrKey} />); // Push to an rows-array
}
// Return rows
return <tbody>{rows}</tbody>;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create a new component like below:

Pass key and data to your `ObjectRow` component like this:

```
export const ObjectRow = ({key,data}) => {
    return (
      <div>
          ...
      </div>
    );
}
```

Create a new component `ObjectRowList` to act like a container for your data:

```
export const ObjectRowList = (objectRows) => {
    return (
      <tbody>
        {objectRows.map((row, index) => (
          <ObjectRow key={index} data={row} />
        ))}
      </tbody>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if this will work for your situation, but often [map][1] is a good answer.

If this was your code with the `for` loop:

```
<tbody>
    for (var i=0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        <ObjectRow obj={objects[i]} key={i}>
    }
</tbody>
```

You could write it like this with the `map` function:

```
<tbody>
    {objects.map(function(object, i){
        return <ObjectRow obj={object} key={i} />;
    })}
</tbody>
```

`objects.map` is the best way to do a loop, and `objects.filter` is the best way to filter the required data. The filtered data will form a new array, and `objects.some` is the best way to check whether the array satisfies the given condition (it returns Boolean).

Comment: Can you add the missing link to "map" (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today)?

Answer (score 5):

You could do the following to repeat a component `numrows` times

```
<tbody>{Array(numrows).fill(<ObjectRow />)}</tbody>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is what I used in most of my projects up to now:

```js
const length = 5;
...
<tbody>
    {Array.from({ length }).map((_,i) => (
        <ObjectRow key={i}/>
    ))}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 5):

try this one please

```
<tbody>
   {Array.apply(0, Array(numrows)).map(function (x, i) {
     return <ObjectRow/>;
   })}
</tbody>
```

or

```
{[...Array(numrows)].map((x, i) =>
   <ObjectRow/>
)}
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use .map() for loop in reactjs

```
    <tbody>
        {items.map((value, index) => {
          return <li key={index}>{value}</li>
        })}
      </tbody>
)
```

Answer (score 5):

A one liner (assuming numrows is a number):

```
<tbody>
  {
    Array(numrows).fill().map(function (v, i) {
      return <ObjectRow/>
    })
  }
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 4):

If numrows is an array, as the other answers, the best way is the `map` method. If it's not and you only access it from JSX, you can also use this [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) method:

```
<tbody>
    {
      [...Array(numrows).fill(0)].map((value,index)=><ObjectRow key={index} />)
    }
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to add elements to an array and render the array of elements.
This can help reduce the time required to re-render the component.

Here's some rough code that might help:

```
MyClass extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super(props)
        this.state = { elements: [] }
    }
    render() {
        return (<tbody>{this.state.elements}<tbody>)
    }
    add() {
        /*
         * The line below is a cheap way of adding to an array in the state.
         * 1) Add <tr> to this.state.elements
         * 2) Trigger a lifecycle update.
         */
        this.setState({
            elements: this.state.elements.concat([<tr key={elements.length}><td>Element</td></tr>])
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You *have* to write in JSX:

```
<tbody>
    {
        objects.map((object, i) => (
            <ObjectRow obj={object} key={i} />
        ));
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: Why do you *have* to write in JSX?

Answer (score 4):

```
<tbody>
   numrows.map((row,index) => (
      return <ObjectRow key={index}/>
   )
</tbody>
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code for some context?

Answer (score 4):

```
render() {
  const elements = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

  const items = []

  for (const [index, value] of elements.entries()) {
    items.push(<li key={index}>{value}</li>)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {items}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways to loop inside JSX

1. Using a *for* loop

   ```
   function TableBodyForLoop(props) {
     const rows = []; // Create an array to store list of tr

     for (let i = 0; i < props.people.length; i++) {
       const person = props.people[i];
       // Push the tr to array, the key is important
       rows.push(
         <tr key={person.id}>
           <td>{person.id}</td>
           <td>{person.name}</td>
         </tr>
       );
     }

     // Return the rows inside the tbody
     return <tbody>{rows}</tbody>;
   }
   ```
2. Using the [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) array *map* method

   ```
   function TableBody(props) {
     return (
       <tbody>
         {props.people.map(person => (
           <tr key={person.id}>
             <td>{person.id}</td>
             <td>{person.name}</td>
           </tr>
         ))}
       </tbody>
     );
   }
   ```

Full example: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-meitner-yztif

The following React Docs will be helpful

- *[Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)*
- *[Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)*

Answer (score 4):

It's funny how people give "creative" answers using a newer syntax or uncommon ways to create an array. In my experience working with JSX, I have seen these tricks only used by inexperienced React programmers.

The simpler the solution - the better it is for future maintainers. And since React is a web framework, usually this type of (table) data comes from the API. Therefore, the simplest and most practical way would be:

```
const tableRows = [
   {id: 1, title: 'row1'}, 
   {id: 2, title: 'row2'}, 
   {id: 3, title: 'row3'}
]; // Data from the API (domain-driven names would be better of course)
...

return (
   tableRows.map(row => <ObjectRow key={row.id} {...row} />)
);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can only write a JavaScript expression in a JSX element, so a *for* loop cannot work. You can convert the element into an array first and use the `map` function to render it:

```
<tbody>
    {[...new Array(numrows)].map((e) => (
         <ObjectRow/>
    ))}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 4):

Having the JSX content in the map can be clunky syntax. Instead you can do this:

```
const ObjectRow = ({ ... }) => <tr key={}>...</tr>

const TableBody = ({ objects }) => {
  return <tbody>{objects.map(ObjectRow)}</tbody>;
}
```

This is shorthand for

```
{ objects.map(object => ObjectRow(object))
```

If ObjectRow is set up to take the same keys that are in the `object`, this will work great.

Note - You may need to set the `key` prop when the ObjectRow is rendered. It can't be passed in through the function call.

---

*More notes* - I've run into a few places where this technique is a bad idea. For example, it doesn't go through the normal create component path and won't default prop values for example, so do beware. Still, it's handy to know about and is useful sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

If you are used to Angular and want a more React-like approach:

Try using this simple component with auto hashing and optional trackBy similar to Angular's.

#### Usage:

```
<For items={items}>
    {item => <div>item</div>}
</For>
```

#### Custom key/trackBy:

```
<For items={items} trackBy={'name'}>
    {item => <div>item</div>}
</For>
```

#### Definition:

```
export default class For<T> extends Component<{ items: T[], trackBy?: keyof T, children: (item: T) => React.ReactElement }, {}> {
    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                {this.props.items.map((item: any, index) => <Fragment key={this.props.trackBy ?? item.id ?? index}>{this.props.children(item)}</Fragment>)}
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

#### React Dev Tools:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

use map to looping

```
 Array.map(arrayItem => {
return <ObjectRow arrayItem={arrayItem}/> // pass array item in component
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Hello my developer friend! you can use this for make a loop looks like "for" inside the JSX react for essay! just use crt c plus crt p inside your project and enjoy!

```
<>{Array(6).fill({}).map((d, i) => (<p>Hi from item number {i}</p>)))}</>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have seen one person/previous answer use .concat() in an array, but not like this...

I have used *concat* to add to a string and then just render the JSX content on the element via the jQuery selector:

```
let list = "<div><ul>";

for (let i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
    list = list.concat(`<li>${myArray[i].valueYouWant}</li>`);
}

list = list.concat("</ul></div>);

$("#myItem").html(list);
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the standard of today maximum developer, use a structure like this:

```
 let data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "name1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "name2"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "name3"
  },
  {
    id: 100,
    name: "another name"
  }
];

export const Row = data => {
  return (
    <tr key={data.id}>
      <td>{data.id}</td>
      <td>{data.name}</td>
    </tr>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>{data.map(item => Row(item))}</tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

In the JSX, write your JavaScript action inside HTML or any code here, **`{data.map(item => Row(item))}`**, use single curly braces and inside a map function. Get to know more about [map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp).

And also see the following output [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-kapitsa-du6jy).

Answer (score 3):

```
const numrows = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

cosnt renderRows = () => {
    return numros.map((itm,index) => <td key={index}>{itm}</td>)
}

return <table>
    ............
    <tr>
        {renderRows()}
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside your render or any function and before return, you can use a variable to store JSX elements. Just like this -

```
const tbodyContent = [];
for (let i=0; i < numrows; i++) {
    tbodyContent.push(<ObjectRow/>);
}
```

Use it inside your *tbody* like this:

```
<tbody>
    {
        tbodyContent
    }
</tbody>
```

But I'll prefer *map()* over this.

Comment: Ohh I almost forgot that map return an array of jsx element and this is not, so will update my answer soon until then use map method.

Comment: Updated the solution, this should work fine.

Comment: *Why* do you prefer *map()*?

Comment: Map by default return a new array and you can directly use it inside your JSX and get the same result as you will get using `for` loop with less headache. If you use `for` loop you need to declare a separate array variable for storing result calculated inside loop, that's not the case using `map` that is why I'll prefer map over normal loop for react.

Answer (score 3):

```
function PriceList({ self }) {
    let p = 10000;
    let rows = [];
    for(let i=0; i<p; i=i+50) {
        let r = i + 50;
        rows.push(<Dropdown.Item key={i} onClick={() => self.setState({ searchPrice: `${i}-${r}` })}>{i}-{r} &#8378;</Dropdown.Item>);
    }
    return rows;
}

<PriceList self={this} />
```

Answer (score 2):

### Simple way

You can put numrows in *state* and use *map()* instead of a *for* loop:

```
{this.state.numrows.map((numrows , index) => {
      return (
        <ObjectRow
          key={index}
        />
```

Answer (score 2):

It is looping through a set of data, creating a new React Component for each item in the data set. This can be achieved using the map() method of JavaScript.

For example, if you have an array of objects called "data" and a React Component called "ObjectRow":

```
const rows = data.map((item, index) => <ObjectRow key={index} {...item} />);
```

Then you can render the rows inside the tbody tag like this:

```
<tbody>{rows}</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is not directly possible in React JSX.**

You can do the following:
First generate a new array with the length you need;

```js
let filledArray = new Array(numRoiws).fill(0); // 0 here for example, choose what you want
```

Then loop over them in the React JSX

```html
<tbody>
  {filledArray.map((arrayItem) => (
    <Component />
  ))}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score -1):

In JSX, you cannot directly use a loop statement like `for` within the JSX code. Instead, you can use JavaScript expressions and functions to achieve the desired result. Here are a few approaches you can take:

1. Using Array.map():
   You can create an array of the desired length and use the `map` function to render the `<ObjectRow />` component multiple times. Here's an example:

```
<tbody>
  {Array(numrows).fill().map((_, i) => (
    <ObjectRow key={i} />
  ))}
</tbody>
```

In this approach, `Array(numrows).fill()` creates an array of length `numrows` and then `map` is used to iterate over each element. The `_` argument is the current element (which we don't need in this case), and `i` is the index. We set a unique `key` prop for each rendered component to satisfy React's requirements.

2. Using a loop outside JSX:
   You can use a regular JavaScript loop outside the JSX code and store the resulting components in an array. Then, you can render the array of components within the JSX. Here's an example:

```
// Outside JSX
const rows = [];
for (let i = 0; i < numrows; i++) {
  rows.push(<ObjectRow key={i} />);
}

// Inside JSX
<tbody>
  {rows}
</tbody>
```

In this approach, you create an empty array called `rows` and use a `for` loop to push the `<ObjectRow />` components into it. Then, you can simply render the `rows` array within the JSX.

Both these approaches achieve the same result of rendering multiple instances of the `<ObjectRow />` component based on the value of `numrows`.

Answer (score -9):

You can not use any loop or other extra methods directly in JSX. Instead what you can do is make separate function for that and make loop statement and in that function return your component
Example for above code:

```
function renderObjectRow (){
   for (var i=0; i < numrows; i++) {
       return  <ObjectRow/>
     } 
}

<tbody>
{renderObjectRow()}
</tbody>
```

Comment: It is important to understand that this answer is not only wrong but will hurt you performance quite bit, because the function will be called and recreate the components on each render.