# Looping in JSX files

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render a dynamic list of elements using React, i.e. I have a javascript array `elems = ['foo','bar']` and I would like to generate

```
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to do this purely in JSX. Is there any convenient way to do this (an "equivalent" of angular `ng-repeat`)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [loop inside React JSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The beauty of React/JSX is that you basically just write JavaScript. So if you have a list of things and want to create a list of components, just `map` the list:

```
<ul>
  {items.map(item => <li>{item}</li>)}
</ul>
```

(and it's also really concise with arrow functions)

Comment: Does the child always have to be an Array? Is there any way to say `var ul = <ul></ul>` and `var li = <li></li>` then somehow appendChild to ul before returning it?

Comment: I think you can only add children to an existing React element by using `React.cloneElement`. But you can write `var ul = <ul>{li}</ul>;` or `var ul = <ul><li></li></ul>;`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no *pure* JSX way to do this (that I know of).  There is no equivalent to `ng-repeat` in React. But, JSX isn't really *pure* in the same way that Angular templates are.  They compile down to JavaScript, after all.

The best way is to loop the JSX and add it to an array:

```
render: function() {
        var elems = ['foo','bar'];
        var listItems = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            listItems.push(<li>{elems[i]}</li>);
        }
        return (
          <ul>
              {listItems}
          </ul>
        );
}
```

You still can use JSX inside the loop as you `push` into the array:

```
listItems.push(<li>{elems[i]}</li>);
```