# Not being able to pass props from a parent component to a child component

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I need to pass `props` to a child component `Product` but i don't know what i'm missing here.

**Parent Component:**

```
var Products = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){..},
  deleteProduct: function(){..},
  updateProduct: function(){..},
  render: function(){
    var products = _.map(this.state.products, function(product){
      return(
        <Product key={product.id} product={product} handleDeleteProduct={this.deleteProduct} handleEditProduct={this.editProduct} formData={this.props.formData}/>
      )
    });
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th colSpan="4">Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {products}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}
});
```

**Child Component:**

```
var Product = React.createClass({
 console.log(this); //props: handleDeleteProduct: undefined, handleEditProduct: undefined
 handleEdit: function() {
  e.preventDefault();
  data = {..};
  $.ajax({
    ..,
    success: (function(_this) {
      console.log(_this); //props: handleDeleteProduct: undefined, handleEditProduct: undefined
      return function(data) {
        _this.setState({
          edit: false
         });
        return _this.props.handleEditProduct(_this.props.product, data);
      };
    })(this)
  });
 }
});
```

I'm able to use `key` and `product` as a props inside the component but not `this.props.handleDeleteProduct` and `this.props.handleEditProduct`.
I think may be i'm using the `props` inside the `success` callback of the `$.ajax` and then may be some thing related to async request. Not sure.

The error i'm getting is

```
Uncaught TypeError: _this.props.handleEditProduct is not a function
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here. I tried to loop directly in between `<tbody>` but still no luck.
Also here i'm calling the functions like `this.deleteProduct` as a reference but not by function call. And if i do by calling by function then it is reporting `execjs` error.

I took this as a reference for looping inside `JSX`: [loop inside React JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx)

But no luck. Please help.

Comment: I'm not seeing a `handleEditProduct` function on `Product`

Comment: Also, what is the point of this line `formData={this.props.}`? Is that a typo?

Comment: @guavacat: its written inside the success: `return _this.props.handleEditProduct(_this.props.product, data);`

Comment: @taylorc93: corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `handleEditProduct={this.editProduct}`, when the function is called `updateProduct` in your parent component.  Change it to `handleEditProduct={this.updateProduct}` and I'll bet it works

EDIT:

Since that didn't work, I looked a little harder and I think I see what the problem is.  I'm fairly sure that `_` doesn't autobind `this` like `React.createClass` does.  So when you map over your products here:

```
var products = _.map(this.state.products, function(product){
      return(
        <Product key={product.id} product={product} handleDeleteProduct={this.deleteProduct} handleEditProduct={this.editProduct} formData={this.props.formData}/>
      )
    });
```

`this` is not set to your react element.  Try keeping a reference to `this` before you `map`, explicitly bind `this` to your map function, or use ES6 arrow functions: https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#arrows-and-lexical-this. The simplest way to achieve what you want would be to save `this` in a variable:

```
var self = this;
var products = _.map(this.state.products, function(product){
          return(
            <Product key={product.id} product={product} handleDeleteProduct={self.deleteProduct} handleEditProduct={self.editProduct} formData={self.props.formData}/>
          )
        });
```

You can also use `bind` to achieve the same effect: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: I missed it but no luck. The error would be different if that was the case.

Comment: Try console logging what `this` is outside of your ajax call and also what `_this` is inside of the success callback and post what those are

Comment: I have posted the console.logs in the question just now. For quick reference they are both null:
`//props: handleDeleteProduct: undefined, handleEditProduct: undefined`

Comment: Can you please give me an example of how to give reference to `this`? I tried to put `this.editProduct` in a variable and used it in place of `this.editProduct` but no luck.

Comment: Oh Nice. Very nice. Can you please elaborate how to identify such situations while writing the code? i have seen many times that people use `bind` after the function ends.

Comment: `this` in javascript is determined entirely by what the "call-site" of the function is.  In your case, you are calling `_.map`, so `this` will be set to `_`.   If you want a much better explanation, this book is about as good as it gets:https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes.  Chapter 1 and 2 should cover everything you'd need to know