# Reactjs not showing markup properly from render() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am still in progress of learning Reactjs.

I am trying to populate table headers within a table row.

Somehow the code written below is treating the generated table headers via the renderTableHeaders() function as pure text only.

```
module.exports = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      defaultTableHeaders: [
        'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
      ]
    }
  },

  renderTableHeaders: function() {

      var markup = [];

      var defaultTableHeaders = this.state.defaultTableHeaders;

      for (var index = 0; index < defaultTableHeaders.length; index++) {
        markup.push('<th>' + defaultTableHeaders[index] + '</th>');
      }

      return markup;
  },

  render: function() {

    return (
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {this.renderTableHeaders()}
        </tr>
      </thead>
    );
  }

});
```

When I modify the render() function to below then it would work properly.  Any idea why?

```
  render: function() {

    return (
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>a</th><th>b</th><th>c</th><th>d</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jsx syntax to create and push elements to the array:

```
markup.push(<th>{defaultTableHeaders[index]}</th>);
```

Comment: ouch, the solution is as simple as that.  I didn't realize I couldn't treat the markup as string.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes, so in your `renderTableHeaders(`) you're returning an array.
So when you do: `{this.renderTableHeaders()}`
its really just a javascript array with all the tags you need.
Try using `{markup}` instead of calling the function directly.
Check out this answer here:
[loop inside React JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx)

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that your `renderTableHeaders` function returns a string instead of returning actual JSX markup.

Please try this:

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      defaultTableHeaders: [
        'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
      ]
    }
  },

  renderTableHeaders: function() {
    var defaultTableHeaders = this.state.defaultTableHeaders;

    return defaultTableHeaders.map(function (header) {
      return (
        <th>{header}</th>
      );
    })
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {this.renderTableHeaders()}
        </tr>
      </thead>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: What are the differences between creating a for loop and push each markup statement into an array in my original code versus using the map() function in the renderTableHeaders() function?  Thanks

Comment: Since `map` returns a transformed version of your original array it's more suitable for this type of cases, it requires less code and it looks a bit more readable. 
Plus, is the recommended way in React samples: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children