# JSX for...in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Given this object:

```
lst socials = {
  foo: 'http://foo'
}
```

I want to loop through it in JSX. This works:

```
let socialLinks = []
let socialBar
for (let social in socials) {
  socialLinks.push(<li>
                     <a alt={social} href={socials[social]}>{ social }</a>
                   </li>)
}
if (socialLinks) {
  socialBar = <div className='align-bottom text-center'>
                <ul className='list-inline social-list mb24'>
                  {socialLinks}
                </ul>
              </div>
}
```

But this doesn't (social undefined):

```
let socialBar
if (socials) {
  socialBar = <div className='align-bottom text-center'>
                <ul className='list-inline social-list mb24'>
                  for(let social in socials)
                  {<li>
                     <a alt={social} href={socials[social]}>{ social }</a> // social is undefined
                   </li>}
                </ul>
              </div>
}
```

What is the reason `social` is undefined in the 2nd example? I assume there is a scoping issue with the inner brackets but I have not been successful fixing it.

I can do do a `forEach` with object keys and do as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx) but that's not much different than my working example.

To be clear - I have it working, I simply wish to be clearer on the scoping problem (or syntax error if so) in my 2nd example.

Comment: Surround your `for` loop with `{}` and try. Although it might work, usually what is done is use the `.map()` array method in order to achieve the same result.

Comment: @DiegoCardoso - no go. That yields a syntax error when I try. Which is odd as I thought things in bracket could be any JS but it doesn't like a for loop. Using a `map` in the same brackets works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSX is just sugar that gets transpiled to a bunch of function calls of `React.createElement`, which you can find the docs for here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.createelement

```
ReactElement createElement(
  string/ReactClass type,
  [object props],
  [children ...]
)
```

Basically your JSX goes from

```
<div style="color: white;">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

to

```
React.createElement('div', { style: { color: 'white' } }, [
  React.createElement('div', {}, [])
])
```

For the same reason you can't pass a loop to a parameter in a function, you can't put a loop into JSX. It would end up looking like

```
React.createElement('div', { style: { color: 'white' } }, [
  React.createElement('div', {}, for (;;) <div></div>)
])
```

which doesn't make sense at all because you can't pass a for loop as a param. On the other hand, a map call returns an array, which is the correct type for the third parameter of React.createElement.

React is still a virtual dom library at the end of the day, but JSX just makes it more familiar to write. [hyperscript](https://github.com/dominictarr/hyperscript) is another good example of a vdom library, but where `JSX` is not standard. Their example on their README is similar to what React would look like without JSX:

```
var h = require('hyperscript')
h('div#page',
  h('div#header',
    h('h1.classy', 'h', { style: {'background-color': '#22f'} })),
  h('div#menu', { style: {'background-color': '#2f2'} },
    h('ul',
      h('li', 'one'),
      h('li', 'two'),
      h('li', 'three'))),
    h('h2', 'content title',  { style: {'background-color': '#f22'} }),
    h('p',
      "so it's just like a templating engine,\n",
      "but easy to use inline with javascript\n"),
    h('p',
      "the intension is for this to be used to create\n",
      "reusable, interactive html widgets. "))
```

Answer (score 3):

In your JSX you can't have a for loop. So even if you have `{}` around your for loop it doesn't work. Instead use a map as shown in the below code. Assuming your data `socials is an array` and not just an object.

If socials is an object  you need to use `Object.keys(socials).map(function(key)){}`

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let socialBar = null;
    let socials = [{
  foo: 'http://foo'
}]
if (socials) {
  socialBar = <div className='align-bottom text-center'>
                <ul className='list-inline social-list mb24'>
                  {socials.map(function(social, index) {
                     
                     return <li key={index}>
                     <a alt={index} href={social.foo}>{ social.foo }</a> 
                   </li>
                    
                  }) }
                </ul>
              </div>
}
    return (
      <div>{socialBar}</div>
    )
  }


}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Are there any docs on this? I can see that it doesn't work and that a `map` does - as I said I have it working so I am not so much looking for another solution as a deeper understanding of the jsx/scope syntax.

Comment: @Yashua JSX is just sugar that gets transpiled to a bunch of function calls. It becomes something like `React.createElement(x, y, [React.createElement(x, y, [])])`. For the same reason you can't pass a loop to a parameter in a function, you can't put a loop into JSX. React is like hyperscript https://github.com/dominictarr/hyperscript in this way because it's a virtual dom library. A map call returns an array, which is the third parameter of `React.createElement`. A for loop as a param is just broken syntax like `console.log(for (;;) console.log(hi))` would be.

Comment: @AR7 thank you that is the answer I was looking for. Please post as an answer.