# React JSX loop only second child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a JSX like:

```
 <table>
   <thead> value </thead>
   <tr> values </tr>
 </table>
```

How can I iterate `<tr>` alone for 10 times?

Comment: How does this question differ from your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/41726222/218196 Don't ask questions twice.

Answer (score 1):

This is the es6 version of the answer.

```
render () {
  const values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  return (
    <table>
      <thead></thead>
      {values.map((item) =>  {
        return (
          <tr key={item}>
            <td>{item}</td>
          </tr>
        );
      })}
    </table>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `for` loop will do:

```
renderTableRow() {
  let trs = []
  for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    trs.push((<tr>{this.props.listOfItems[i]}</tr>))
  }
  return trs
}
```

in the table it can look like this:

```
<table>
  <thead></thead>
  {this.renderTableRow()}
</table>
```

I understand you asked this question not too long ago and was given this link, [looping inside JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx). Make sure you check it out if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

React allows you to run JavaScript functions within your JSX using curly braces. You can either write a JavaScript function in which you're returning an array of `<tr>` (which JSX will render correctly). Or, probably more preferably, you can hold the values you want to display within an array and use a `map()` function within your JSX. For example:

```js
render() {
  const values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  return (
    <table>
      <thead></thead>
      {values.map(function(currValue){
        return (
          <tr key={currValue}>
            <td>{currValue}</td>
          </tr>
        );
      })}
    </table>
  );
}
```

There are several examples you can find accomplishing running a loop in JSX, such as: [loop inside React JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx)