# How to return same value base on parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is my code

```
function returnEmptyTd(num) {
        for(var i=0; i <= num; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            return(
                <td class="empty"></td>
            )
        }
    }
```

If num is 2, I will get two empty td return.
If num is 5, I will get five empty td return.

But I can only get one  with this code, even I pass 5 to num.

How to fix it?

Comment: Are you using React or something like that ? How do you expect the result to be ? An array ? If so, why not just pushing your `td`s inside an array and returning it ?

Comment: @Ninetainedo Yes, I am

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx

Comment: Don't forget that you have to use `className` in place of css' `class` when using jsx

Comment: you're better off just mapping it (using `map`). You could do it inside the return section of render if it suits the logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` means return and **end the function**.

I guess you are using React and want to render some `<td>` based on given `num`

In React you can return an array for this purpose:

```
var result = []
for(var i=0; i <= num; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    result.push(<td key={i} className="empty"></td>);
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You Could use an array like below instead of return.

```js
function returnEmptyTd(num) {
  var tds = [];
  for(var i=0; i <= num; i++) {
   
    tds.push('<td class="empty"></td>')
  }
  return tds;
 }
 
 var tds = returnEmptyTd(3);
 console.log(tds);
```