# Outputting n instances of a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create `n` instances of a React component.

What is a good terse way to do this give that JSX can only contain expressions?

I currently am trying the following:

```
<Wrapper>
  {repeat(n)(i => <MyComponent i={i} />}      
</Wrapper>

function repeat(n) {
    return cb => Array(n).fill(null).forEach((_, i) => cb(i));
}
```

Comment: 'JSX can only contain expressions' isn't entirely true.  I recommend doing any formatting in your render method prior to returning the formatted JSX.  Also, check out the [Thinking in React tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

Comment: Ok thank you. Can you give me an example of a statement that is permitted inside JSX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use as much JavaScript als you like :)

```
render() {
  const lst = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  return (
    <div>
      {lst.map(itm => <span key={itm}>{itm}</span>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you do not have a `key` ready, you can use the second argument of the map callback which is the index in the array. [More info on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

In your specific case where you do not have an array but just a number:

```
render() {
  var times = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    times.push(<MyComponent key={i} i={i} />);
  }
  return <Wrapper>{times}</Wrapper>;
}
```

Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22877049/540352) on how to use `for` loops. It's not quite as nice but it also works. I believe the React team has planned to make working with arrays in JSX more straight forward.

If you have just a number, and do not want to use a for loop, you could also "fake" it, for example by using [string.repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat). Not sure if this is very readable though :)

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {'a'.repeat(10).split('').map((_, i) => <MyComponent i={i} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I've used map many times to do this.  Readers observe:  The 'key' attribute is important.  (React will complain if you don't have it)

Comment: I guess the point of the question is that I don't have a list to map over. Instead I simply have a number.