# Show array elements in mapped array in ReactNative

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My Reducer is :

**Reducer:**

```
const initialState = {
  1: {
     id: '1',
     name: 'Name1',
     number: 11,
     myArray:["P1tag1","P1tag2", "P1tag3"]
    },
  2: {
     id: '2',
     name: 'Name2',
     number: 22,
     myArray:["P2tag1","P2tag2", "P2tag3"]
    }
}
```

Used `mapStateToProps` and mapped `newData`. I'm rendering the data like this:

```
   const renData = Object.keys(this.props.newData).map((key, idx) => {
    let data = this.props.newData[key]
      return (
          <View>
            <Text>{data.name} </Text>

            <Text>{data.number} /Text>

            <Text>
              myArray // <= How do I show the items from myArray here? 
            </Text>
          </View>

      )
  })
```

`data.name` and `data.number` are displayed fine. I'm trying to figure out how to show the array `myArray` from `data`.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [loop inside React JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply map through them:

```
<View> //or any other wrapper here
   {data.myArray.map((item, index) => <Text key={index}>{item}</Text>)}
<View>
```

Comment: `Cannot find variable: index` Tried in a `Text` tag and outside it .. same error.

Comment: That's not possible. `index` is the respective `item`'s index in `myArray`.