# How do I use for loops with react?

Tags: reactjs, for-loop, bootstrap-4

I am very new to react and all I really want is a simple for loop that creates menuitem elements for each user in my array with the title of it being their firstname. So this is how I would write it, but I have no clue of how to do this in react. I think it should be with a map maybe but I cant seem to get it to work either hopefully anyone out here can help me.

```
for (var i = 0; i < Users.length; i++) {
  <MenuItem eventKey=[i]>User.firstname[i]</MenuItem>
}
```

Comment: You can't iterate within JSX elements with `for` loop.  use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead.

Comment: @MostafizRahman is correct. A react component expects either a string, another component, or an array of components. For loops do not return any of these. This is why we have to store the value of the for loop in a variable and return the variable. See [How To Loop Inside React JSX - React FAQ](https://victorofoegbu.com/notes/loop-inside-react-jsx-faq) or this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22877049/8828126)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The `render` method of your component, or your stateless component function, returns the elements to be rendered.

If you want to use a loop, that's fine:

```
render() {
    let menuItems = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < Users.length; i++) {
        menuItems.push(<MenuItem eventKey=[i]>User.firstname[i]</MenuItem>);
    }
    return <div>{menuItems}</div>;
}
```

More common would be to see a more functional style, such as using a map to return the array of elements:

```
render() {
    return <div>
    {
        Users.map((user, i) =>
            <MenuItem eventKey=[i]>User.firstname[i]</MenuItem>)
    }
    </div>;
}
```

Note that in either case, you are missing the `key` property from each element of your array, so you will see warnings. Each element in an array should have a unique key, preferably some form of ID rather than just the array index.

Answer (score 9):

With [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) you can do:

```
Users.map((user, index) => (
  <MenuItem eventKey={index}>user.firstname</MenuItem>
));
```