# React js loop through array received from blade

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, loops, laravel-blade

Im using React js for the front-end in a Laravel project. From a controller , im passing an array to my view:

```
return view('shopCart')->with('items',$it);
```

Now in the view a could loop through the array like this:

```
@foreach($items as $item)
                <li><input type="checkbox" name=""> <span>{{$item->Name}}</span> <span></span>  <span>{{$item->Cost}}</span> </li>
@endforeach
```

And this is working fine. But i would like to make the view more dynamic(by the way this is a list of products in a shopping cart). For example , by default all the checkboxes will be checked, meaning the user is buying all items. I want that if the user uncheck a box, the total price changes . So i made a React component , and im passing the $items array to that component via props:

```
<div id="listshops" datas={{$items}}></div>
```

And there's the component:

```
class Items extends Component {
    render() {


        return (
            <div className="container">
               <a href="/products">Continue shopping</a>
               //LOOP THROUGH THE ARRAY OF PRODUCTS
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Items;


window.onload=function(){
if (document.getElementById('listshops')) {
    var data=document.getElementById('listshops').getAttribute("datas");
    ReactDOM.render(<Items items={data}/>, document.getElementById('listshops'));
}

}
```

How can i loop through that array i passed to the component so i can display the product like in the @foreach in blade ?

Comment: This is a duplicate question of the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46908480/how-do-i-use-for-loops-with-react

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array#map`, don't "loop". You're mapping one dataset (your products) into another dataset of equal size (React components)

```
const { items } = this.props;

return (
  <div className="container">
    <a href="/products">Continue shopping</a>
    {items.map(({ Name, Cost }) => <li key={Name}>
      <input type="checkbox" name="" /> <span>{Name}</span> <span></span>  <span>{Cost}</span>
    </li>)}
  </div>
);
```

Often when you `map`, it's a good indication that you're using a component that could be reusable too. This could be a cleaner approach for you:

```
const Product = ({ Name, Cost }) => (
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="" />
    <span>{Name}</span>
    <span></span>
    <span>{Cost}</span>
  </li>
);
```

Then in your render:

```
const { items } = this.props;

return (
  <div className="container">
    <a href="/products">Continue shopping</a>
    {items.map(({ Name, Cost }) => <Product {...{Name, Cost}}/>}
  </div>
);
```