# How to use for-loop in map in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary, for-loop

can you please help me, how to add "for" loop in this code - the goal is to show only 3 comment from all comments, that are scanned with the .map.

```
<div>   {data.statement.comments.reverse().map((comment) => (
           
          <div key={comment.id} style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}>
             <strong>
                {comment.user.firstName} {comment.user.lastName}
              </strong>
              <small className={Classes.TEXT_MUTED} style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>
                {formatCreatedAt(comment.createdAt)}
              </small>
            
                        
            </div>
      ))}

     
        </div>
```

I tried to put it here -but as I found out it doesn=t work in JSX.

```
 <div>   {data.statement.comments.reverse().map((comment) => (
           //for Loop
          <div key={comment.id} style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}>
             <strong>
                {comment.user.firstName} {comment.user.lastName}
              </strong>
              <small className={Classes.TEXT_MUTED} style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>
                {formatCreatedAt(comment.createdAt)}
              </small>
            
                        
            </div>
      ))}

     
        </div>
```

Or would you recommend to use another way to solve the task?

Comment: Worth reading - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46908480/how-do-i-use-for-loops-with-react

Answer (score 1):

You can use this, no need for a `for loop`

```
data.statement.comments.reverse().slice(0,3).map((comment)...
```

adding `slice` here will not change the original array, it will create a new one, it will contain only 3 elements. 0 is where to start the slice and 3 is number of items you want.

To answer your question why `for` does not work there, try this code.

```
let a = [1,2,3,4];
let c = a.map(el => {
  console.log(el);
  return el + 1;
})
// c = [2, 3, 4, 5];
```

as you can see here, Map return a new array, for does not (for is not a function), if you take a closer look at your React code, map will return only JSX, for can't do that since it is not a function.

Here another example

```
{[1,2,3].map(el => <p> el </p>)}
// is equale to
// <p>1</p><p>2</p><p>3</p>
// which is a valid JSX
```

so any thing inside `{}` get excuted and it get replaced by what it return, the `map` can return, but for can't since it isn't a function, a rule of thumb: you can use ony what return, and if you must use `for`, use it inside a fucntion and call it from your JSX `{}`