# Render JSON data using React

Tags: json, reactjs

I have this JSON data I am trying to render as a list.

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Bill"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Sarah"
}]
```

I am trying to display the data such that I pass a title of the data and the id's as parameters from Parent class to Child class and the latter prints the data as list.

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <Child
          title={"Group 1"}
          options={this.props.data.name}
        />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's my Child class:

```
export default class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    var data=this.props;
    var title=this.props.title;
    var name=this.props.name;
    return (
      <ul>
        <h4>{title}</h4>
        <div>{this.props.map(item=>
          <li>{name}</li>
        )}
        </div>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

What I don't understand is how to use map in the Child class to display data. I know that I shouldn't write `this.props.map(item=>`. I am new to React and would appreciate some help fixing this.

Comment: What is your JSON object variable called?

Comment: Please refer this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx

Comment: It's called "data" like I wrote `this.props.data.name` in Parent class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's don't use map in the child... try this:

```
let data = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Bill"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Sarah"
}]
```

user `map` in parent component:

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <div>Group 1</div>
        <ul>
          {data.map(item => <Child
            options={item}
          />)}
        </ul>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

enhance the  child component :

```
export default class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    let {options:{name}} = this.props
    return (
      <li>{name}</li>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first you have to use `JSON.parse()` on your json, so it becomes a javascript object, you also have to make sure you are passing the props to your Child right. Then, you can map like this:

`this.props.data.map((item,i) => <li key={i}>{item.name}</li>)`

Comment: Is this the right way to pass an attribute of the JSON object, say "name" ?`{this.props.data.name}`

Answer (score 1):

Just pass your data as prop from parent component and you can access it in child component.

```js
let {Component} = React;

const data = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Bill"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Sarah"
}]

class Child extends Component {
  render() {
   let {data, title} = this.props;
   
    return (
      <ul>
        <h4>{title}</h4>
        <div>{data.map(item=>
          <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>
        )}
        </div>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <Child
            title={"Group 1"}
            data={this.props.data}
          />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

You can also call map method inside parent component and for each element in your data render Child component. Also only `li` element can be direct child of `ul`.

```js
let {Component} = React;
const data = [{"id": "1","name": "Bill"}, {"id": "2","name": "Sarah"}]

class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    let {name} = this.props;
    return <li>{name}</li>
  }
}

class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <h1>{"Group 1"}</h1>
          <ul>{this.props.data.map(item => {
                return <Child key={item.id} {...item} />
              })}
          </ul>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Update: for nested children you can `React.cloneElement` to dynamically add child nodes.

```js
let {Component} = React;
const data = [{ "id": "1", "name": "Bill" }, { "id": "2", "name": "Sarah", "childnodes": [{ "id": "3", "name": "Some name", "childnodes": [{ "id": "4", "name": "Last" }]}] }]

class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    let {name} = this.props;
    return <li>
      {name}
      {this.props.children ? <ul>{this.props.children}</ul> : ''}
    </li>
  }
}

class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderNodes = this.renderNodes.bind(this);
  }
  
  renderNodes(data) {
    return data.map(item => {
      let child = <Child key={item.id} {...item} />
      
      if(item.childnodes) {
        child = React.cloneElement(child, {
          children: this.renderNodes(item.childnodes)
        })
      }
      
      return child;
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <h1>{"Group 1"}</h1>
          <ul>{this.renderNodes(this.props.data)}</ul>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to modify the second approach for recursive check for example the child nodes like here but passing only `props.name` as argument in `Child` component: `[{
 "id": "1",
 "name": "Bill"
}, {
 "id": "2",
 "name": "Sarah",
 "childnodes": [{
  "id": "3",
  "name": "4"
 }]
}]`

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with your code:

1. You need to pass your JSON object down from your Parent to your Child-component. If it's called `data`, then do:

   ```
   <Child
     title={"Group 1"}
     options={this.props.data}
   />
   ```

   I suggest using `data` instead of `options` to prevent confusion, but that's up to you. Also, you cannot pass `this.props.data.name` because `this.props.data` is an array of objects.
2. Now that `options` is an array, we can properly use `map()`. You were trying to use `map()` on `this.props`, which is incorrect. So try instead:

   ```
   <div>
     {this.props.map(item=>
       <li>{item.name}</li>
     )}
   </div>
   ```
3. Also, `<ul>` elements can only have `<li>` as their direct children. You have placed `<h4>` and `<div>` elements as its children. Instead wrap those inside an `<li>` element.

---

#### Full demo:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Bill"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Sarah"
  }
];

class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child
          title={"Group 1"}
          options={this.props.data}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var title = this.props.title;
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>{title}</h4>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div>
              {this.props.options.map(item=>
                <li>{item.name}</li>
              )}
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent data={data} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```