# method of pushing components to an array and also passing props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is this method of pushing components  to an array?

```
days.push(

        <Day day={day}
          selected={selected}
          select={select}/>
      );
```

I read this code but couldn't understand few things in it.

```
class Week extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let days = [];
    let {date,} = this.props;
    const { month,selected,select, } = this.props;
    console.log(`Inside weeks ${month.toString()}`);
    console.log(`Selected weeks ${selected.toString()}`);


    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

      let day = {
          name: date.format("dd").substring(0, 1),
          number: date.date(),
          isCurrentMonth: date.month() === month.month(),
          isToday: date.isSame(new Date(), "day"),
          date: date
      };



      days.push(

        <Day day={day}
          selected={selected}
          select={select}/>
      );
      console.log(`days inside return is ${days.selected}`);
      date = date.clone();
      date.add(1, "day");
    }


    return (

      <div className="row week" key={days[0]}>
        {days}
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

I am quite puzzled at this step in code where apart from passing properties to another class ,it has also been pushed to an array and later same has been returned

```
<div className="row week" key={days[0]}>
        {days}
      </div>
```

Comment: props is not pushed into an array, components (React Elements) are. you should learn more about react

Comment: @ReiDien Can you just explain the above process or link me to something to read ?

Comment: first, in react you can display a variable. `<div>{variable}</div>`. basically it just creates an array of React Elements and then renders it. thats all no fancy stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to dynamically render element inside a loop.
you render them and push them inside an array and then render the array (as the array is built of react elements, it will just render).
Have a look here: [Loop inside React JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx)