# React - Render complex json data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I just started out with React and I have a use case where I need to display form data that is already fetched from an API.
The form data is pretty complex and I am also having a tough time using JSX. 
The data can be found here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nhjmzv

The idea is to display the data in two sections, each section with the title and below the title, display the form labels and their corresponding values. Kind of like a read only view of the form. The data is completely dynamic so might grow in the number of key-value pairs.

Any help or direction to go in is appreciated.
I tried for in loop to iterate but somehow React doesn't like it and learnt a bit about that as well. I am also going through other SO questions as I post this. Thanks in advance.

Edit - I have access to lodash if that helps
Edit 2 - Changed stackblitz link to the edit version

Comment: Link to edit/view: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nhjmzv

Answer (score 0):

**#New answer**

This should help you.
Beware that I'm learning React too.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ytp2wh

**#Previous answer**

You can fetch data with fetch() method.

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

A basic fetch request is really simple to set up. Have a look at the following code:

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
  });
```

Here we are fetching a JSON file across the network and print it to the console.

Then, instead of using for-loop, try [map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) to display data in JSX.

Sample:

```
 render() {
    return (  
      <div>
        { 
          movies.map((movie) => (          
            <div 
                key={movie.id} 
                title={movie.title} 
                description={movie.description}
                preview={movie.preview}
            />                      
          ))                    
        }  
      </div>
    )
  }
```

See also [Loop inside react JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx)

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear with the question. I am not looking at making the API call. I already have the data after the API call. It is the json object rendering I am having a problem with. And the data is complex json which needs to be traversed.

Comment: You should add the structure of the JSON to your question (make it as short as possible) and also what you actually want to do with it.

Comment: I have posted a stackblitz link that contains the data

Comment: By my opinion, you should post on codereview instead, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I edited the answer with the code snippet you needed

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough solution of what you're trying to achieve: [React JSON Form](https://react-pwjvc8.stackblitz.io)