# for loop not working in render function reactjs

Tags: reactjs

m looping using for in render function
its giving syntax error can we not use this way in react
following is the code

```
render(){
    return(
        <table>               
             for(var i=0;i<this.props.TRlength;i++)                  
               <TRcomponent TDlength={this.state.tdLength} />                                                
        </table>
        )
}
```

error it throws 
             `/src/Table.js
              Syntax error: D:/my-app1/src/Table.js: Unexpected token (17:50)

```
           <table>

             for(var i=0;i<this.props.TRlength;i++)//error here
                                              ^

                  <TRcomponent TDlength={this.state.tdLength} />
              `
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop inside React JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx)

Answer (score 1):

React doesn't play well with for loops in the render. You cannot create children for a parent that does not exist yet. You need to create the children first.

This [article](https://blog.cloudboost.io/for-loops-in-react-render-no-you-didnt-6c9f4aa73778) goes into detail about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can store it in a variable and then use it in jsx

```
render() {
  var rows = [];
  for (var i=0;i<this.props.TRlength;i++) {
     // note: we add a key prop here to allow react to uniquely identify each
     // element in this array. see: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html
     rows.push(<TRcomponent TDlength={this.state.tdLength} key={i} />);
  }
  return < table >{rows}</table>;
}
```