# Render multiple elements based on a number rather than mapping through an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, rendering

I'm familair with mapping through and array to render something for each number in an array. But what is an effective way to accomplish the same thing using a number.

I've found myself in a situation where I have an `integer` representing number of pages and a component `<Page>` which takes the prop `pageNumber`.

I've got the following render function in place:

```
renderPages() {
  for (let i = 1; i < this.state.numPages; i++) {
    return <Page pageNumber={1} />;
  }
}
```

The `renderPages` function is implemented as follows in my class `render` function:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.renderPages()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I understand that once the first return occures the `renderPages` is exited. So in the end it only renders the first page. How can I render more pages here?

Comment: Ah right, good approach. I was thinking of that I wasn't sure whether or not it'd be the best solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another preferences (shorter version):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51335795/9206753 (my previous answer)

To loop for a number of times and return, you can achieve it with the help of [`from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
  <div>
    {Array.from(Array(this.state.numPages)).map((item, index) =>
      <Page key={index} pageNumber={index + 1} />
    )}
  </div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, going to tweak you answer to match my problem better but this worked more reliably for me than the other solutions posted!

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle glad it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Append to an array and then return the array.

```
renderPages() {
    const arr = []
  for (let i = 1; i <-this.state.numPages; i++) {
    arr.push(<Page pageNumber={1} />)
  }
    return arr
}
```

or you can do this without using a function by creating an empty array,

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {(new Array(this.state.numPages)).map((item, i)=><Page pageNumber={i} />)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
renderPages() {
    const arr = []
  for (let i = 1; i <-this.state.numPages; i++) {
    arr.push(<Page pageNumber={1} />)
  }
    return arr
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.renderPages().map((item)=>(item))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to explain what this code does. Whilst it is useful to have the code, the OP (and everyone else) would benefit from an explanation.