# I want to repeat "★" as many times as a number in state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to repeat "★" as many times as a number in state in React.

What should I do?

I want to printing like this.

js ★★★
ts ★★
html ★★★

```js
state = {
  myScores: [
    { name: "js", score: 3 },
    { name: "ts", score: 2 },
    { name: "html", score: 3 }
  ]
}

...

const myScores = this.state.myScores.map(
  ({name, score}) => (
    <div>
      {name}
      {
        for(let i=0; i<score; i++) {
          <div>★</div>
        }
      }
    </div>
  )
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Replace for loop with <div>{★.repeat(score)}</div>

Comment: You should have a look at [Loop inside React JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22876978/218196) to learn how to write loops in/with JSX in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is replace for loop with.

`<div>{"★".repeat(score)}</div>`

Reason why your code was not working the way you expected is.

1. In practice the OP's code will throw an error since you cannot have JavaScript statements inside JSX (i.e. it won't render anything). very well explained by **@FelixKling** in comments.
2. Since while iterating through for loop you're adding a new div every time which is a block element.so it will take up the complete width.
   you can read more about block elements here 
   https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp

Comment: It should be `"★".repeat(score)`.

Comment: @FrankerZ Yeah i missed the quotes thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: *"you're adding a new div every time which is a block element"* Maybe in theory. In practice the OP's code will throw an error since you cannot have JavaScript statements inside JSX (i.e. it won't render anything).

Comment: @FelixKling yeah true. i just answered in that context only i have update the answer. Thanks :)