# extract object items in object array at react template

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, object

I'm newbies in react and javascript. I try to use this below data in react template. They're object array so i want to every items in this object array print separately in HTML (react template).  Anyone can help me, i have code below, please help:

```
const fakeData = [
  {
    MOP: 'MOP',
    code: '#1180-xxxx',
    date: '10-08-2018',
    status: 'Pending Order',
  },
  {
    MOP: 'MOP1',
    code: '#1180-xxxx1',
    date: '11-08-2018',
    status: 'Pending Order',
  },
  {
    MOP: 'MOP2',
    code: '#1180-xxxx2',
    date: '12-08-2018',
    status: 'Pending Order',
  },
];

export class TransactionPage extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { fakeData };
  }

  render() {
    const { classes, intl } = this.props;
    return (
      <Page>
        <Helmet>
          <title>{intl.formatMessage({ ...messages.header })}</title>
          <meta
            name="description"
            content={<FormattedMessage {...messages.meta} />}
          />
        </Helmet>
        <PageContent>
          <Paper>
            <Grid container>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={5} md={4} lg={3}>
                <List className={classes.list} disablePadding>
                  // show the item here
                </List>
              </Grid>

              <Hidden xsDown>
                <Grid item sm={7} md={8} lg={9}>
                  <Grid
                    container
                    direction="column"
                    spacing={16}
                    className={classes.details}
                  >
                    <Grid item xs={12} className={classes.center} />
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                      <Typography variant="h6">CREDIT DEBIT</Typography>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                      <Divider />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} />
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </Hidden>
            </Grid>
          </Paper>
        </PageContent>
      </Page>
    );
  }
}

TransactionPage.propTypes = {
  intl: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  TransactionPage: makeSelectTransactionPage(),
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    dispatch,
  };
}

const withConnect = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
);

const withReducer = injectReducer({ key: 'TransactionPage', reducer });
const withSaga = injectSaga({ key: 'TransactionPage', saga });

export default compose(
  withStyles(styles),
  injectIntl,
  withReducer,
  withSaga,
  withConnect,
)(TransactionPage);
```

I want this code transform as output below in the page:

```
             <Grid container>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={5} md={4} lg={3}>
                <List className={classes.list} disablePadding>

                  <ListItem button>
                    <span>MOP</span>
                    <span>#1180-xxxx</span>
                    <span>10-08-2018</span>
                    <span>Pending Order</span>
                    <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                      <ArrowIcon />
                    </ListItemSecondaryAction>
                  </ListItem>

                  <ListItem button>
                    <span>MOP1</span>
                    <span>#1180-xxxx1</span>
                    <span>11-08-2018</span>
                    <span>Pending Order</span>
                    <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                      <ArrowIcon />
                    </ListItemSecondaryAction>
                  </ListItem>

                  <ListItem button>
                    <span>MOP2</span>
                    <span>#1180-xxxx2</span>
                    <span>12-08-2018</span>
                    <span>Pending Order</span>
                    <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                      <ArrowIcon />
                    </ListItemSecondaryAction>
                  </ListItem>

                </List>
              </Grid>
```

i'm using react, how to loop them in react template.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop inside React JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map it like this pseudo...

```
var formatted = fakeData.map((item, idx) => {
return(
 <ListItem key={idx}>
   <span>{item.MOP}</span>
   <span>{item.code}</span>
   <span>{item.date}</span>
   <span>{item.status}</span>
</ListItem>
)
})
 return(
 <List>
 {formatted}
 </List>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just create a map with JSX:

```
<List className={classes.list} disablePadding>
{fakeData.map((item, i) => <ListItem key={item.MOP+"_" + i} button>....</ListItem>) }
</List>
```

Comment: Just to add on top of that, if you want to add or remove this list of items, don't use index as key. In react index as a key is antipattern — for more info 
https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: @MohitTilwani that's way I've use something that look like id from data + index.

Comment: I know but just want to say this explicitly as it could be the case that MOP is not unique, so just so that everyone knows why exactly it is like that.