# Programmatically adding components with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm fairly new to `React` and I'm trying to add new components to already exsisting, but I am not sure how to do that.

So here I have the list of my `Seances` and the button to add more:
**SeanceManager.js**

```
return (
  <MDBRow>
    <MDBCol md="6">
      <MDBCard>
        <MDBCardBody>
          <form>
            <p className="h4 text-center py-4">Sign up</p>
            <div className="grey-text">
              <MDBInput
                label="Type your email"
                icon="envelope"
                group
                type="email"
                validate
                error="wrong"
                success="right"
              />
              <MDBInput
                label="Type your password"
                icon="lock"
                group
                type="password"
                validate
              />
            </div>
            <div className="text-center py-4 mt-3">
              <MDBBtn color="cyan" type="submit" onClick={props.submitLogin}>
                Log in
              </MDBBtn>
            </div>
          </form>
        </MDBCardBody>
      </MDBCard>
    </MDBCol>
  </MDBRow>
);
```

By pressing the button to add more, a modal view pops up and at the end it has a `submit` button that should add the `Seance`.
**AddSeanceModal.js**

```
return (
  <Modal
    {...this.props}
    size="lg"
    aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
    centered
  >
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
      <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">Add Seance</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>
      <div>
        <form>
          {/*First row*/}
          <MDBRow>
            <MDBCol md="4">
              <div className="custom-file">
                <input
                  type="file"
                  className="custom-file-input"
                  id="inputGroupFile01"
                  aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01"
                />
                <label className="custom-file-label" htmlFor="inputGroupFile01">
                  Choose file
                </label>
              </div>
            </MDBCol>
          </MDBRow>

          {/*Second row*/}
          <MDBRow>
            <MDBCol md="4">
              <MDBInput
                onChange={this.changeHandler}
                type="text"
                id="materialFormRegisterPasswordEx4"
                name="algus_aeg"
                label="Algus Aeg"
                required
              />
            </MDBCol>
            <MDBCol md="4">
              <MDBInput
                onChange={this.changeHandler}
                type="text"
                id="materialFormRegisterPasswordEx4"
                name="lopp_aeg"
                label="Lõpp Aeg"
                required
              />
            </MDBCol>
          </MDBRow>

          {/*Third row*/}
          <MDBRow>
            <MDBCol md="4">
              <MDBInput
                onChange={this.changeHandler}
                type="text"
                id="materialFormRegisterPasswordEx4"
                name="aja_samm"
                label="Aja Samm"
                required
              />
            </MDBCol>
          </MDBRow>

          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.props.onHide}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <MDBBtn color="success" type="submit" className="float-right">
            Add Seance
          </MDBBtn>
        </form>
      </div>
    </Modal.Body>
  </Modal>
);
```

And finally the `Seance` itself:
**Seance.js**

```
return (
  <div
    className="card"
    style={{ marginBottom: "7px" }}
    onClick={() => this.setState({ modalShow: true })}
  >
    <div className="card-body">
      <h5 className="card-title">Seance nr: {this.props.id}</h5>
      <p className="card-text">Start aeg: {this.props.startDate}</p>
      <p className="card-text">End aeg: {this.props.endDate}</p>
      <button type="button" className="close float-right" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
      </button>
      <ResultModal id={1} show={this.state.modalShow} onHide={modalClose} />
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

I also made a fiddle on sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/qloo1vqr7j?fontsize=14

At the moment I have 4 static `Seances`, but it should start with 0 and add more once you add them.  
Also the `X`on the Seance should remove it.

I have tried creating a list on state in `SeanceManager.js`, but I have not understoond how to add components to the list from another component `AddSeanceModal`.

Comment: You can use a `for` loop to programmatically add components, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx

Comment: Where dou you save the information stored in your `Seance`s? Where is the code that `renders` each `Seance`?

Comment: Well they should be stored locally, but at the moment they aren't stored anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few code choices that are holding your application back from being dynamic.

First, you'll need to utilize a `container component` that handles all things related to `Seance` state. This includes, `adding`, `removing` and `viewing`. All of this needs to be handled by a parent that updates its children according to what current in its `state`. Please follow this guide to understand [containers vs components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0).

Second, you need to refactor how you're utilizing `Seances`. They need to be stored as an `array` within the parent's `state`. As you have it now, it's hard-coded with 4 `<Seances />` that can't be removed/updated.

Instead, you should create an `array` of `object`s like so within `state`:

```
seances: [
  { id: "1", startDate: "2019-04-10 10:28:05.926-07", endDate: "2019-05-10 10:28:05.924-07" },
  { id: "2", startDate: "2019-04-11 11:28:05.926-07", endDate: "2019-05-11 11:28:05.924-07" },
  { id: "3", startDate: "2019-04-12 12:28:05.926-07", endDate: "2019-05-12 12:28:05.924-07" },
  ...etc
];
```

You'll utilize [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map over this seances `array` and [implicitly](https://jaketrent.com/post/javascript-arrow-function-return-rules/) `return` these seances dynamically (to make easier to read, I'm writing your `<Seance id={id} />` component inline):

```
<div>
  {seances.map(({ id, startDate, endDate }) => (
    <div key={id}>
     <h1>Seance nr: {id} </h1>
     <p>Start date: {startDate}</p>
     <p>End date: {endDate}</p>
     <button type="button" onClick={() => handleDeleteSeance(id)}>X</button>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

Now you'll remove these items from the `seances` array by utilizing [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) by a seance's `id` property. When a user clicks the "X" button it calls `this.handleDeleteSeance` with the specific seance `id`:

```
handleDeleteSeance = id => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState, // spread out any previous state not related to "seances"
    seances: prevState.seances.filter(seance => seance.id !== id) // this translates to: compare each "seance" within "seances" and implicitly return any that do NOT match the "id" that was clicked
  })
};
```

To add an item to the `seances` array, you'll utilize the [spread operator](https://codeburst.io/a-simple-guide-to-destructuring-and-es6-spread-operator-e02212af5831), and add an `object` with properties that were collected from a `form`:

```
handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { id, startDate, endDate } = this.state;

  if (!id || !startDate || !endDate } return null; // if any properties are missing, don't add an item yet

  this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState, // spread out any previous state not related to "seances"
    seances: [...prevState.seances, { id, startDate, endDate } ] // this translates to: spread out any previous seances and add a new object with "id", "startDate" and "endDate"
  });  
}
```

---

**Working with arrays example** (since this a client-only implementation, I decided to filter by array position so I don't have to have to deal with generating unique `id`s; however, you can utilize [uuid](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-uuid#readme) to generate these dynamic `id`s if you wish):

[image: Edit Class Component - Filter Data by Array Index]

---

**Other notes**:

- One of your components contains a `let modalClose = () =>
  this.setState({ modalShow: false });` within the `render` method.
  This is invalid and should be defined as a class method.
- Structure your components to be reusable. You have some components that are, but then you have some that reside within another component (like `FileInput`). As your application grows, you may need to use `FileInput` elsewhere for another form.
- Utilize ES6 syntax **throughout** your project to simplify your code. For example you can [deconstruct](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/destructuring-in-javascript-es6-ee963292623a) `props` for your `Login` component like so: `const Login = ({ submitLogin }) => ( <MDBRow>...etc</MDBRow>);`.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, there is a lot to look into. I am pretty sure this is what I am looking for and will help me. I will accept this answer as soon as I get it working. Thank you a lot for your answer.

Comment: Can you answer this one question please. In my example I have `AddSeanceModal.js` and it was a component and I tried to switch it to a container as per your example. But the `<Modal>` in that class requires `{...this.props}` and so does the `<Button>` in the end of that class. I tried passing `show` and `onHide` as proptypes like in yout codesandbox example you are doing with `age` and `name`, but that does not seem to cut it. What am I supposed to do with that?

Comment: In that case, you wouldn't deconstruct `props` if both `Modal` and `Button` need the `onHide` function. It'd be: `const AddSeanceModal = props => ( <Modal {...props}>...<Button onClick={props.onHide}>Close</Button>...</Modal>`. HOWEVER, if the `Modal` doesn't need `onHide`, then you can do something like `const AddSeanceModal = ({onHide, ...rest}) => ( <Modal {...rest}> ...<Button onClick={onHide}>Close</Button> .. </Modal>)`. You partially deconstruct `props` via `...rest`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Rest_syntax_(parameters)

Comment: Ideally, you'd only have one container that updates all its children (not multiple). However, you can have a stateful `form` component that, once submitted, passes back its `state` to the `parent` it resides in. For example: `<AddSeance handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />` resides in `App`. Now `AddSeance` has a `handleSubmit` prop via `this.props.handleSubmit`. This is especially useful if you want to make this `AddSeance` component self-contained (it handles its own `state` separately from `App`), but it still utilizes a class method from `App`.

Comment: Alright, I got it working. There are still some errors but I'm pretty sure I'll be able to figure them out. Thank you a lot, I will give you the bounty as soon as it lets me.

Comment: You bet. If you find that you're passing down props too many times and/or have way too many mounted children that are mounted but invisible, then you should look into redux: https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started. It acts like a container for your entire application, but it doesn't need to traverse the children to reach a component that requires some `state`. Instead, you just directly `connect` to the child that needs the `state`. However, your project, as of now, doesn't need this yet.

Comment: Did most of it from your example and finally got it all working. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Awesome. That was my intention. I didn't want to fix your code, otherwise, if I did then you wouldn't learn nearly as much by doing it on your own.