# Reading array elements with forEach in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach

I am a beginner in React. I have a pretty simple code. (There are other questions which seems to be duplicate of this but they ain't. Please read the contents also not just the question heading before marking duplicate.)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Likes extends Component {
  render() {
    var music=["linkin park", "led zaplin", "regina spector", "bruno mars"];
    return(
    {
      music.forEach(function (value, index, array) {
          <h1>{value}</h1>
       })
      }
    );
  }
}
export default Likes;
```

Is it correct way or should I use `state`. I wanted to keep it as simple as possible. But I'm getting this.[image: (see attached image)]

What is that I am missing. What else I should know.

PS: I dont have any other separate component or code. Everything is there inside the class itself.

Comment: Use `.map` and `return` the <h1>

Comment: Ok. But then I'll have to set `keys` also. Correct me If i'm wrong.

Comment: use below code

music.map((value, index) {
          <h1>{value}</h1>
       })

Comment: @TanZeel index will provide you key that you can use, see above

Comment: @Punneet Yes. But I've been told that its not the best way. As index will change as we add or remove elements from that `music` array. Is it so?

Comment: @Tanzeel As you remove or add elements to array, your index will get reset automatically with new array.

Comment: @tanzeel if you add/remove value from array and setState then component will automatically rerender and index will initialize again

Comment: The problem with your code is a `syntaxError` and not the use of `forEach` (though you will have to use map due to the fact that `map` returns an array that react will use to render but `forEach` itself does not return anything. Try `[1,2,3].forEach(a => a)` and `[1,2,3].map(a => a)` in your browser console to see the difference). The syntaxError can be fixed like ```const elements = []
    music.forEach(function(value, index, array) {
      elements.push(<h1>{value}</h1>)
    })

    return elements``` With `forEach` you build an array of elements urself but `map` does this automatically

Comment: @LuckySoni.  Actually I implemented the solution and got my problem solved. Wanted to answer my question but I cannot do so as someone has marked my question duplicate. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 11):

You need to iterate array using `map`,

```
{music.map(function (value, index, array) {
    return <h1 key={index}>{value}</h1>
  })
}
```

Comment: Oh. Ok. So I cannot use `forEach` here ?

Comment: Correct. Use `map` and return `h1` element.

Comment: And don't worry about the key, index will get reset when array addition or deletion happens.

Comment: React internally works with `index`, we don't work with index manually.

Comment: @ravibaglu91. wow. I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: Keep this in mind: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html - We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state.

Comment: you can use forEach, just you have to take a different approach. Write a render method check for this solution and replace `map` with `forEach`.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63791485/12003816