# How to integrate Javascript variable into ReactJS JSX style element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styles, jsx

I have a javascript array of image sources. Now I need to implement each of the image source in individual box background. I am trying to put the array element into React JSX style element like below (demo code)

```js
    const box = []

    for(const [index, image] of images.entries()) {
        box.push(
           <Box key={index} style={{background: 'url(image)'}}>
              Some code goes here.......
           </Box>
    )}

    return(<div>{box}</div>)
```

Hope I can make you understand my problem. Please help, any alternative way is always welcome. thank you in advance

Comment: Use something like: `const imageBoxes = images.map((image, index) => <JSX />)`. You can then render `<div>{imageBoxes}</div>` into your main render, or do the `.map` directly in there.

Comment: @JamieDixon Thanks for the response but my question was how to integrate javascript variable into React JSX style element. Like in the "style={{background: 'url(image)'}}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`For` loop won't work directly in `render` function. you can use `map` instead

```
images.map((image, index) => (
  <Box key={index} style={{background: `url(${image})`}}>
       Some code goes here.......
  </Box>
))
```

Check this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-frost-4iz90

You can check this as well: [Loop inside React JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response but my question was how to integrate javascript variable into React JSX style element. Like in the "style={{background: 'url(image)'}}". Let me edit the code, it is creating confusion

Comment: I have updated the example. You can use template literal to define the variable. Here is the link to read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: I have also added an example with the same use case. Hope this will help.