# What does it mean that "JSX maps to function calls"

Tags: reactjs, for-loop, jsx

I'm learning react and I was trying to find a way to loop inside JSX when I came across this stackoverflow link - [Loop inside React JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx)
The author of the question says that 
**I realize and understand why this isn't valid JSX, since JSX maps to function calls**
I don't understand what he meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that ...

```
<MyButton color="blue" shadowSize={2}>
  Click Me
</MyButton>
```

... compiles to the **function call**:

```
React.createElement(
  MyButton,
  {color: 'blue', shadowSize: 2},
  'Click Me'
)
```

... as described here: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html