# React multiple a tag inside li tag

Tags: reactjs

I can render nested data with React.
For example:

1. text1, text2
2. text1, text2, text3

I combine strings to get "text1, text2"

> allSynonymText += synonym.SynonymText + ', ';

I want to make links instead of combined text inside of a li tag.
For example:

1. link1, link2
2. link1, link2,  link3

This is my data:

[image]

My code:

```
<div>
<p><span>Synonyms</span></p>
<ul>
    {word.Definitions.map((definition, index) => {
        if (definition.Synonyms !== null && definition.Synonyms.length > 0) {
            let allSynonymText = '';
            definition.Synonyms.map((synonym) => {
                allSynonymText += synonym.SynonymText + ', '; // I combine texts here
            })
            return <li>{index + 1}. {allSynonymText}</li>
        }                            
    }
    )}
</ul>
</div>
```

This is what I get:
[image]

What I try to achieve: (Please look at 6th li tag)

[image]

I am new to React. I searched and tried many things but I couldn't achieve it.

How can I insert multiple links inside of a li tag?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop inside React JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx)

Comment: @DanO unfortunately no. I can create multiple li tags inside of ul tag. All of the examples are for this logic. I need to place links inside of a li tag. I need a second iteration in rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` between `{}` in JSX in order to return an array.

And you can use a fragment `<>{}</>` to return the link and your comma as a single element.

Putting those together you get something like:

```
return <li>
  {index + 1}.
  {definition.Synonyms.map(synonym => (
    <>
      <a href={`/synonyms/${synonym.synonymID}`}>
        {synonym.synonymText}
      </a>,
    </>
  )}
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped me a lot.  I made a few changes to your answer and it worked. I used `<span>` instead of `<>` and I added `return` inside of the `Synonyms.map`

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code to this:

```
<div>
<p><span>Synonyms</span></p>
<ul>
    {word.Definitions.map((definition, index) => {
        if (definition.Synonyms !== null && definition.Synonyms.length > 0) {
            return <li>
                {index + 1}.
                {definition.Synonyms.map(synonym => {
                    // return new span for each synonym
                    // and place the link inside of the span
                    return <span><a href={`/?wq=${synonym.SynonymText}`}>{synonym.SynonymText}</a> , </span>
                }
                )}
            </li>
        }                            
    }
    )}
</ul>
```

This is the result:

[image]

Thanks to @AlexWayne