# How to place an HTML tag in an object?

Tags: html, reactjs, object, pchart

I want to render a list from an array of objects in React. The 'answer' key contains the following text...

```
Question: blah,
Answer: `List title
         The biggest benefits of Kin are:
         1.
         2.
         3.
         4.
`
```

I would like to add spacing between the list items. Like I've demonstrated here...

```
Answer: `List title
         The biggest benefits of Kin are:
         <br/>
         1.
         <br/>
         2.
         <br/>
         3.
         <br/>
         4.
```

Adding any html tag between the list items doesn't work as the tag gets rendered like so:

1.<br [innerHTML]>2.<br [innerHTML]>...

Any ideas?

Comment: > You can see what I'm trying to achieve here.


actually i cant

Comment: Apologies, edited.

Comment: It seems your question is similar to this question: [Loop inside React JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx)

Comment: @EvanMeredith-Davies ah ic now, upvoted since you made the effort to edit your question :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop inside React JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the **map** function for iterating over the array of answer list.

Here's how it will look:

```
import React from 'react'
export default class TestRoute extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const ANSWER_OBJECT =
        {
            title: "Answer Title 1",
            answers: [
                "The biggest benefit of ....",
                "1. ",
                "2. ",
                "3. "
            ]
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <h3>{ANSWER_OBJECT.title}</h3>
                {ANSWER_OBJECT.answers.map((item) => <div>{item}</div>)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

RESULT:

**Answer Title 1**
The biggest benefit of ....
1.
2.
3.

If you have answer in the form of String instead of array, you could use the **split** method to convert it to array.

```
render() {
        const answerString =
            `The biggest benefit of ....
            1. Point 1
            2. Point 2
            3. Point 3
            `

        return (
            <div>
                {answerString.split("\n").map((item) => <div>{item}</div>)}
            </div>
        )
    }
```