# useState doesn't update when called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, use-state

I am building a restaurant website template. In the project, I do have a modal box with two arrow buttons to change pages. I keep track of the `pageNumber` variable via useState. Unfortunately, the value never updates, which prevents pages from changing.

Here is the Menu.js component:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState } from 'react';

const Menu = () => {
    let [pageNumber, switchPage] = useState(1);
    
    let dish = {
        categories: [
            'proin blandit',
            'suspendisse non',
            'fermentum ultrices',
            'volutpat vulputat'
        ],

        names: [
            ['Sed fermentum', 'Sapien nec lobortis', 'Tristique in suspendisse', 'Pellentesque mattis elit', 'Vel interdum velit'],
            ['Nam nisi quam', 'Donec non viverra', 'Morbi suscipit mattis', 'Sed dignissim nisi', 'Aliquam vitae'],
            ['Curabitur ante mi', 'Nulla a felis', 'Donec porta convallis ', 'Vestibulum viverra ', 'Nullam viverra '],
            ['Vestibulum odio', 'Mauris neque ligula', 'Praesent iaculis nunc', 'Cras sollicitudin est', 'Class aptent taciti ']
        ],

        prices: [
            [13.99, 11.99, 15.99, 17.99, 21.99],
            [22.99, 20.99, 18.99, 16.99, 24.99],
            [11.99, 21.99, 31.99, 25.99, 15.99],
            [6.99, 8.99, 10.99, 4.99, 8.99]
        ]
    }

    let iterator = Math.abs(pageNumber % 4);
    
    let lineBreak = window.innerWidth <= 750 ? <br/> : undefined;

    return (
        <Router>
            <section className='menu'>
                <i className='fas fa-chevron-circle-left' id='menu-arrow-left' onClick={() => switchPage(pageNumber - 1)}></i>
                <h1 className='dish-category'>You are viewing {dish.categories[iterator]}</h1>
                <Link to='/home'><i className='fas fa-times'></i></Link>
                <ul className='dish-list'>
                    <li className='dish'>{dish.names[iterator][0]} {lineBreak} <span className='price'>{dish.prices[iterator][0]} PLN</span></li>
                    <li className='dish'>{dish.names[iterator][1]} {lineBreak} <span className='price'>{dish.prices[iterator][1]} PLN</span></li>
                    <li className='dish'>{dish.names[iterator][2]} {lineBreak} <span className='price'>{dish.prices[iterator][2]} PLN</span></li>
                    <li className='dish'>{dish.names[iterator][3]} {lineBreak} <span className='price'>{dish.prices[iterator][3]} PLN</span></li>
                    <li className='dish'>{dish.names[iterator][4]} {lineBreak} <span className='price'>{dish.prices[iterator][4]} PLN</span></li>
                </ul>
                <i className='fas fa-chevron-circle-right' id='menu-arrow-right' onClick={() => switchPage(pageNumber + 1)}></i>
            </section>
        </Router>
    )
}

export default Menu;
```

This is how I toggle the modal's visibility:

```
const hideModal = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholder');
    placeholder.innerText = '';
    placeholder.style.display = 'none';

    let container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.style.filter = '';
    container.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
}

const showModal = () => { 
    let placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholder');
    placeholder.innerHTML = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Menu />);
    placeholder.style.display = 'block';
    
    let container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.style.filter = 'blur(8px)';
    container.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
}
```

And this is the corresponding JSX code in App.js:

```
<div id='placeholder'><Menu /> <Contact /></div>
```

Additionally, I have written a test function that detects the clicked place. When I run it on the example above I get a message that I am clicking outside the modal box, even though it's the opposite. The function is run from a different file. It looks like this:

```
let childrenNodes = [
    document.getElementsByClassName('menu')[0], 
    document.getElementsByClassName('dish-category')[0], 
    document.getElementsByClassName('dish-list')[0], 
    document.getElementsByClassName('dish')[0], 
    document.getElementsByClassName('dish')[1], 
    document.getElementsByClassName('dish')[2], 
    document.getElementsByClassName('dish')[3], 
    document.getElementsByClassName('dish')[4], 
    document.getElementsByClassName('price')[0], 
    document.getElementsByClassName('price')[1], 
    document.getElementsByClassName('price')[2], 
    document.getElementsByClassName('price')[3], 
    document.getElementsByClassName('price')[4]
];

const detectPlace = () => {
    window.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        childrenNodes.some((node) => e.target === node) ? console.log('Clicked inside!') : console.log('Clicked outside!');
        console.log(e.target);
    });
}
```

Could you tell me why is it working this way?

Comment: Try `switchPage((prevState) => prevState - 1)` instead of `switchPage(pageNumber - 1)`

Comment: @VitaliyRayets, it's still not working for me, nothing changed

Comment: variable `iterator` not reactive

Comment: @VitaliyRayets, it depends on the `pageNumber` variable, which doesn't change on its' own

Comment: Just wondering, could you wrap the `i` element with onClick into a div (or a) and set the handler to the new div?

Comment: You should either use React or manual DOM manipulations, not both as it's going to create a lot of bugs!

Comment: You could also loop on the data instead of hard-coding each item manually: [Loop inside React JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22877110/1218980)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rendering the contents of `#placholder` with:

```jsx
let placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholder');
placeholder.innerHTML = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Menu />);
```

`ReactDOMServer.renderToString(...)` produces a string containing HTML. This string doesn't include any JavaScript, thus making the result non-interactive.

> #### [renderToString()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring)
>
> ```
> ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element)
> ```
>
> Render a React element to its initial HTML. React will return an HTML
> string. You can use this method to generate HTML on the server and
> send the markup down on the initial request for faster page loads and
> to allow search engines to crawl your pages for SEO purposes.
>
> If you call [`ReactDOM.hydrate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#hydrate) on a node that already has this
> server-rendered markup, React will preserve it and only attach event
> handlers, allowing you to have a very performant first-load
> experience.

If you want an interactive DOM structure you should use the normal `ReactDOM.render(...)` method to render your component.

```jsx
let placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholder');
ReactDOM.render(<Menu />, placeholder);
```

```js
// import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
// import { useState } from 'react';
const { BrowserRouter: Router, Link } = ReactRouterDOM;
const { useState } = React;

const Menu = () => {
    let [pageNumber, switchPage] = useState(1);

    let dish = {
        categories: [
            'proin blandit',
            'suspendisse non',
            'fermentum ultrices',
            'volutpat vulputat'
        ],

        names: [
            ['Sed fermentum', 'Sapien nec lobortis', 'Tristique in suspendisse', 'Pellentesque mattis elit', 'Vel interdum velit'],
            ['Nam nisi quam', 'Donec non viverra', 'Morbi suscipit mattis', 'Sed dignissim nisi', 'Aliquam vitae'],
            ['Curabitur ante mi', 'Nulla a felis', 'Donec porta convallis ', 'Vestibulum viverra ', 'Nullam viverra '],
            ['Vestibulum odio', 'Mauris neque ligula', 'Praesent iaculis nunc', 'Cras sollicitudin est', 'Class aptent taciti ']
        ],

        prices: [
            [13.99, 11.99, 15.99, 17.99, 21.99],
            [22.99, 20.99, 18.99, 16.99, 24.99],
            [11.99, 21.99, 31.99, 25.99, 15.99],
            [6.99, 8.99, 10.99, 4.99, 8.99]
        ]
    }

    let iterator = Math.abs(pageNumber % 4);

    let lineBreak = window.innerWidth <= 750 ? <br/> : undefined;

    return (
        <Router>
            <section className='menu'>
                <i className='fas fa-chevron-circle-left' id='menu-arrow-left' onClick={() => switchPage(pageNumber - 1)}></i>
                <h1 className='dish-category'>You are viewing {dish.categories[iterator]}</h1>
                <Link to='/home'><i className='fas fa-times'></i></Link>
                <ul className='dish-list'>
                    <li className='dish'>{dish.names[iterator][0]} {lineBreak} <span className='price'>{dish.prices[iterator][0]} PLN</span></li>
                    <li className='dish'>{dish.names[iterator][1]} {lineBreak} <span className='price'>{dish.prices[iterator][1]} PLN</span></li>
                    <li className='dish'>{dish.names[iterator][2]} {lineBreak} <span className='price'>{dish.prices[iterator][2]} PLN</span></li>
                    <li className='dish'>{dish.names[iterator][3]} {lineBreak} <span className='price'>{dish.prices[iterator][3]} PLN</span></li>
                    <li className='dish'>{dish.names[iterator][4]} {lineBreak} <span className='price'>{dish.prices[iterator][4]} PLN</span></li>
                </ul>
                <i className='fas fa-chevron-circle-right' id='menu-arrow-right' onClick={() => switchPage(pageNumber + 1)}></i>
            </section>
        </Router>
    )
}

let placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholder');
ReactDOM.render(<Menu />, placeholder);
```

```html
<div id="placeholder"></div>

<link crossorigin rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" />
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@5/umd/react-router-dom.js"></script>
```