# Should I use for loops in ReactJS? Any other way to change multiple elements at once when an Input changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a POS system with ReactJS. Should I use a for loop to calculate the total amount? Is there any other way to do this?

```
let product = testProducts;
let subtotalEl = document.getElementsByClassName("Subtotal");
let quantity = document.getElementsByClassName("Quantity");
for (var i = 0; i < product.length; i++) {
  subtotalEl[i].innerHTML = product[i].UnitPrice * quantity[i].value;
}
```

Comment: There's never a good reason to use `getElementsByClassName` in React (nor `.innerHTML` nor `.value`)

Comment: If you're talking about summing line items: the rendering should be using an (array, object, ...) of line items w/ each item having data (description, quantity, price, ...) and the total should be calculated using that data--not anything in the view layer.

Comment: In your code example, you have made use of absolutely *nothing* that React has to offer.  Maybe look at some of the answers to [Loop inside React JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx)

Comment: Unfortunately, as others have already pointed out, you are using React incorrectly. [Here is a comment I wrote for a similar antipattern explaining what the problem is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71732114/hi-all-am-creating-responsive-navbar-in-react-when-i-clicked-on-toggle-button-i#comment126768178_71732114).

Answer (score 0):

1. You are not using react js, your code looks like JavaScript.
2. Yes, you can use a loop to add, but in React it is recommended to use `map` for iterations.

For example:

```js
const sum = array_object
  .map((item) => item.quantity)
  .reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 1);
```

As you can see, `map` was used to go through the array, and `reduce` to add the values.

Comment: (As a side note, `map` is for transforming lists, not generic iteration, and it's not strictly ReactJS-related.)