# For loop inside Scrollview

Tags: javascript, react-native, for-loop

I try to run the create new feature as many times as the size of my array is, unfortunately I fail.

Main  element code

```
return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          alignContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 20,
            margin: 30,
            color: colors.darkGray,
          }}
        >
          ──────── Skanowane kody ────────
        </Text>
        <ScrollView>
         
        {newHistoryScan(images.qr_test, text[0])}

        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

A function that renders the next item

```
function newHistoryScan(image, result) {

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Image
        source={image}
        resizeMode="contain"
        style={{
          width: 350,
          height: 150,
        }}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {checkResult(result)}}
        >
        <Text
          style={{
            color: 'blue',
            fontSize: 20,
            marginTop: 10,
            marginBottom: 40,
          }}
        >
          {result}
        </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

So, I made a function that works, it displays all the items from the array, unfortunately when I call the newHistoryScan function, the screen on the phone remains white, the items do not appear.

```
function loopItems(){
    for (let a = 0; a < text.length; a++ ){
      console.log(text[a])
      newHistoryScan(images.qr_test, text[a])
  }
}
```

**Console**
[MS Code Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6BMj.png)

**Phone**
[Empty screen - phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9618j.jpg)

If I paste the reference to the newHistoryScan function there, the items are displayed on the phone.

[working screen - phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW0tQ.jpg)

Calling a function that displays elements sequentially and should call this function the number of times

```
<ScrollView>
         
      {loopItems()}

        </ScrollView>
```

Correctly working (direct) function call.

```
<ScrollView>
         
        {newHistoryScan(images.qr_test, text[a])}

        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop inside React JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx)

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is that `loopItems` doesnt return anything. To achieve this with a for loop you would do this:

```
function loopItems(){
    const items = []
    for (let a = 0; a < text.length; a++ ){
      console.log(text[a])
      items.push(
        newHistoryScan(images.qr_test, text[a])
      )
    }
    return items
}
```

I think you should use map instead:

```
 function loopItems(){
   // NOTE: I have no idea where you initialize text or images
   return text.map(item=>{
      console.log(item);
      return newHistoryScan(images.qr_test, item);
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i tried mapping but you did it better - it works now.
Unfortunately my Array don't have unique key prop, how i can add this?
Error from console: Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Comment: convert `newHistoryScan` into a functional component by changing it to this `function NewHistoryScan({image, result}) { ... }`. In `loopItems`  change your mapping a bit

Comment: ```return text.map((item,i)=>{
      console.log(item);
      return <NewHistoryScan image={images.qr_test}  result={item} key={'item-'+(i+1)} />;
  })```