# nested for loop in react render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested-loops

The site is telling me there are many similar questions, but i just couldn't find an answer i'm looking for. I believe it should be an easy one for react pros, as i'm a beginner.

I've got this code inside `render` function:

```
return (
  
  <div>
    <div className="board-row">
      {this.renderSquare(0)}
      {this.renderSquare(1)}
      {this.renderSquare(2)}
    </div>
    <div className="board-row">
      {this.renderSquare(3)}
      {this.renderSquare(4)}
      {this.renderSquare(5)}
    </div>
    <div className="board-row">
      {this.renderSquare(6)}
      {this.renderSquare(7)}
      {this.renderSquare(8)}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

And i want to rewrite it using two nested loops, all I could come up with is this (doesn't work, i try to correct errors, but that just brings me to fresh errors):

```
return (
  <div>
   {for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      <div className="board-row">
       {for (let k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
         {this.renderSquare((j*3) + k)}
       }}
      </div>
   }}
  </div>
```

);

How do i rewrite this code?

Comment: Define "doesn't work", and also share your error messages.

Comment: `{this.renderSquare((j*3) + k)}` I guess will not render component as its not rendering anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lot of workaround for making it work, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx)

My suggestion would be have a good data structure for it.

```js
const board = [
 [ 1, 2, 3 ],
 [ 4, 5, 6 ],
 [ 7, 8, 9 ]
]

return (
  <div>
   {board.map((row, i) => (
      <div key={i} className="board-row">
       {row.map(square => renderSquare(square))}
      </div> 
   ))}
  </div>
)
```

and you cannot use *for loop* inside the render method.
You should use `.map` for it.

Whenever you are rendering an array of elements, don't forget the `key`s.

Read more: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: great, thanks, it works! but i'm gettig warning "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique 'key' prop.%s%s See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.%s" ". Where do i put the key and what should it be?

Comment: Edited the answer. Basically whenever you are rendering an array of elements, you have to pass `key` to every child.

Comment: done that, but the warning didn't disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
const array = [
    {
        className: "board-row",
        squares: [2, 4, 6]
    },
    {
        className: "board-row",
        squares: [1, 2, 3]
    }
]

return (
    <div>
        {array.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <div key={index} className={item.className}>
                    {item.squares.map((square, indexSquare) => {
                        return square;
                    })}
                </div>
            )
        })}
    </div>
)
```