# how to return list inside for loop without breaking

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, material-ui

I have a list of elements and I would like to print 3 of them in cards in every row.

the **problem** with the following code : it prints just the first two elements and the loop stops.

here's my code im using reactjs and mui :

```
const testList = [//my list]

const ListInvoices = (props) => {

const invoicesList = () => {

  for(let i = 1; i <= testList?.length; 3*i){
      let invList = testList?.slice(i-1, 2*i)
      return(
         <Grid container alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
            <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
            {invList ?.map((elt, index) => {
               return(
                 <Grid item>
                     <Card sx={{m: 2}} key={{index}}>
                        {/* content of card */}
                     </Card>
                 </Grid>
               )
             })
            }
            </div>
         </Grid>
      )
  }
}

return(
  <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: "#f6f6f6" }} pt={4} pb={4}>
     <Container maxWidth="lg">
         {invoicesList()}
     </Container>
  </Box>
)
}
```

EDIT :
as the answers suggested, i changed this

```
 for(let i = 1; i <= testList?.length; i*3) 
 //..
 let invList= testList?.slice(i-1, 2*i)
```

to this

```
for(let i = 1; i <= testList?.length; i+3) 
//.. 
let invList = testList?.slice(i-1, 3*i)
```

but the **problem is always there**

thank you in advance

Comment: Is the Grid a CSS Grid? If it is isn't the point to add items to the grid, and let the CSS manage _how_ the grid should appear? That way you could decide how many items appear in a row without having to use JS.

Comment: Grid from mui. I forgot to mention it in the question

Comment: If you look at the [documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/grid/) you can see that you can supply a columns prop, and any number of other props to help you display the right type of grid for your needs.

Comment: @Andy em maybe I didn't get your point. But, i guess the problem has nothing to do with the grid..

Comment: [Some more documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/). It uses flex-box which allows you to define (responsively) how many items fit in one row depending on the parameters it's given.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the relevant info for your problem
[Loop inside React JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx)
But could the problem be when you multiply i by 3,

```
for(let i = 1; i <= testList?.length; 3*i <-- here
```

Because when i = 1, i * 3 = 3, but when i = 3, i * 3 = 9, so it would skip the second row.

Comment: I should put i+3 instead. but the original problem stills

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Seeing that your problem persists, and after reading again your code, I see a small detail that I didn't notice at first. Is your for loop working correctly? I have tried with RunJS and it's been creating infinite loops over and over again.

When you are doing i*3 you are not really updating the value of i, but making a simple declaration that has no further effects. Let me know if that makes sense, but this would be the code after the correction:

```
for(let i = 1; i <= testList.length; i = i + 3) {
```

**Original answer**

I'm not sure if I got your problem right. However, I do see why this line

```
invList ?.map((elt, index) => {
```

returns only 2 cards. I assume it's here where it had to return 3? If so, maybe I have an answer for you.

Mind that when using slice, the end index will not be included.

When applying the following code (extracted from yours):

```
let invList = testList?.slice(i-1, 2*i)
```

If index is 1 and the we have an array as the following one:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

invList will slice from 0 (index - 1) to 1, since 2 (2 * 1) will be the end index that is not included.

Therefore, the third number should be printed with the following small change:

```
let invList = testList?.slice(i-1, 3*i)
```

or

```
let invList = testList?.slice(i-1, 2*i + 1)
```

Having said so, is there any specific reason as of why you are using a for loop? I believe it could be replaced with map, using the second parameter passed at each iteration (the index parameter).

Comment: thank you for the answer. but the original problem stills; it prints just first 3 elements

Comment: I already updated the value from i*3 to i+3 as suggested @Lachlan Jowett. in EDIT section in my question. but the probelm persits. I guess it's because of the return statement in my funtion; return will break the loop for

Comment: I might not have expressed myself clearly. My edit is not about whether to use + or *, but about assigning the new value to the index (i). My suggestion is to use "i = i + 3" instead of "i + 3".

Anyways, yes, the return statement breaks the for loop (I don't know how I haven't noticed haha)

Comment: I changed for(let i = 1; i <= testList?.length; i+3) to for(let i = 1; i <= testList?.length; i = i+3) but it has changed nothing

Comment: It should be the return statement then, as you said. With the return, it should do only one iteration, and within that iteration load three cards. But it would be rendering 1 row, when you seem to want more.

I still think you could use a map instead of a for loop. Or, if you really want to keep it, you can remove the returns and instead do .push() on an external array.

Answer (score 0):

Well a friend of mine gave me a simple solution to achieve what I want, and also @Andy suggested to use the props of mui Grid. so here's the solution's code

```
const testList = [//my list]

const ListInvoices = (props) => {

return(
  <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: "#f6f6f6" }} pt={4} pb={4}>
     <Container maxWidth="lg">
         <Grid container spacing={2} alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
                {testList?.map((elt, index) => {
                    return (
                       <Grid item xs={4}>
                        <Card sx={{m: 2}} key={{index}}>
                        {/*content*/}
                        </Card>
                      </Grid>    
                     );
                  })
                }
     </Container>
  </Box>
)
}
```

so by giving each item of the grid xs=4 (12/4 = 3) that prints in each row 3 cards and returns to new line for the next 3 items and so on ..