# Throwing semicolon error in react js for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I am new to ReactJS and encountered an error when using a simple for loop in my code. The error points to the semicolon within the loop, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Here's the code snippet:

```
const resume = {
interest :['Drawing','Photography','Design','Programming','Computer Science'],

skills :['Web Design with React'],

education :['Wilton High School','Silvermine School of Arts','Codeacademy'],

experience :['Student Technology Intern for Wilton School','Babysitter'],

extracurriculas :['Recycling Club','Gardening Club','Book Club']
    }
    
    function App() {
    
      var len = resume.interest.length;
    
      return (
    
        <>
          for (let index = 0; index < len; index++) {
            <h1>{resume.interest[index]}</h1>
            
          }
        </>
      )
    }
    
    export default App;
```

The error message I'm getting is: "Parsing error : Unexpected token". It seems that the for loop is causing the issue, specifically the semicolon. How can I resolve this error and successfully loop through the resume.interest array to display each interest as an  element?
[This above code throw error like that:Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agR92.png)

But it works when I did

```
<h1>{resume.interest[0]}</h1>
```

without for loop

Comment: [Loop inside React JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx) you may want to check this out

Comment: I answered below but then saw @KhairaniF's comment and realized it's a duplicate, so voting to close [in favor of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx)

Answer (score 0):

All JavaScript in JSX (the HTML-ish part) needs to be wrapped in braces. This would cause a problem when using a for loop, because you can't return more JSX from a for loop, because it's not a function. Instead you'll want to use `map`:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      {resume.interest.map((int) => <h1 key={int}>{int}</h1>)}
    </>
  )
}
```

Any elements returned by a map have to have a `key` prop that is unique, so we're using the same element that's getting passed into the `h1`.

If it helps, you might try using React without JSX, to understand how putting plain JS inside your JSX works. Each tag is just syntax sugar for a function call, and the `children` argument is an array, not arbitrary code, under the hood. Check out [the docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) if you're curious.