# is there a way to create multiple divs using a loop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I want to know if there is a way to create and render multiple elements dynamically instead of having to manually write each one in React. 
Coming from javascript there were options like the following:

```
let parent document.getElementById("parent");
let html = "";
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
html += "<div>Div + (i + 1) + "</div>";
}
parent.innerHTML
```

Or:

```
let parent = document.getElementById("parent");
for (let i=0; i < 10; i++) {
let div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "Div + (i + 1);
parent.appendChild(div);
}
```

i tried for loops, making functions containing only the code for creating multiple divs, tried placing the function or the for loop in different places in my component or even outside of it. also tried looking up online but I can't seem to find an answer and I keep running into errors

Comment: Read more than the accepted answer. ie: this one has a good overview https://stackoverflow.com/a/29629588/13762301 . Also you shouldn't be using direct DOM queries except in very specific circumstances.

Comment: @pilchard I'm more partial to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46975826/283366)

Comment: Fair enough, spread vs Array.from (even I didn't scroll that far ;) )