# execute a for loop inside a div, but giving error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop

i tried to loop and execute a component inside react, but giving error. Map function is used when we have an array, but here i have a number and i want to execute a component 4 number of times.

Error it was giving is :  "Parsing error: Unexpected token (61:23)"

```
<div>
(
for (var i=0; i <4; i++) {
       <StarIcon />
 }
)
</div>
```

Comment: Answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx?rq=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a better way to display your stars :)

```
  <div>
    {Array.from({ length: 5 }).map((_, i) => (
      <StarIcon key={i} />
    ))}
  </div>
```

Comment: Already answered on the duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29629588/215552 :)

Answer (score 0):

> In your form of approach this is how you can properly perform displaying the component you want in a loop.

```
const REPEATED_COUNTS = 4;

const components = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= REPEATED_COUNTS; i++) {
    components.push(<Stars key={i} />);
 }
  return (
    ...
    <div>{components}</div>
  );
};
```