# Elements in a for loop lose hooks in React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm learning React by following the tic-tac-toe exercise shown in [this page](https://react.dev/learn/tutorial-tic-tac-toe#wrapping-up). In the *Wrapping up* chapter, one of the extra assignments is:

> Rewrite *Board* to use two loops to make the squares instead of hardcoding them.

So I went from this:

```
function Board({ xIsNext, squares, onPlay }) {
  function handleClick(i) {
    if (calculateWinner(squares) || squares[i]) {
      return;
    }
    const nextSquares = squares.slice();
    if (xIsNext) {
      nextSquares[i] = 'X';
    } else {
      nextSquares[i] = 'O';
    }
    onPlay(nextSquares);
  }

  const winner = calculateWinner(squares);
  let status;
  if (winner) {
    status = 'Winner: ' + winner;
  } else {
    status = 'Next player: ' + (xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O');
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="status">{status}</div>
      <div className="board-row">
        <Square value={squares[0]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(0)} />
        <Square value={squares[1]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(1)} />
        <Square value={squares[2]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(2)} />
      </div>
      <div className="board-row">
        <Square value={squares[3]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(3)} />
        <Square value={squares[4]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(4)} />
        <Square value={squares[5]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(5)} />
      </div>
      <div className="board-row">
        <Square value={squares[6]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(6)} />
        <Square value={squares[7]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(7)} />
        <Square value={squares[8]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(8)} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

To this, see the changes comment for the difference:

```
function Board({ xIsNext, squares, onPlay }) {

  function handleClick(i) {
    if (squares[i] || calculateWinner(squares)) {
      return;
    }
    const nextSquares = squares.slice();
    if (xIsNext) {
      nextSquares[i] = "X";
    }
    else {
      nextSquares[i] = "O";
    }
    onPlay(nextSquares);
  }

  const winner = calculateWinner(squares);
  let status;
  if (winner) {
    status = "Winner: " + winner;
  }
  else {
    status = "Next player: " + (xIsNext ? "X" : "O");
  }

  /* CHANGES START HERE */
  let content = [];
  let n=0;
  for (let i=0; i<3; i++) {
    let row = [];
    for (let j=0; j<3; j++) {
      row.push(<Square key={"square-" + n} value={squares[n]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(n)} />);
      n++;
    }
    content.push(<div key={"row-" + i} className="board-row">{row}</div>);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="status">{status}</div>
      {content}
    </>
  );
}
```

The Board is correctly drawn and also the keys for the elements in the array are generated correctly as requested by the compiler:

[image: running buggy app]

However, if I click on a square, the cell doesn't get the X/O sign as it should, also the game tracker just logs the first move and ignores any subsequent click on other squares.

[image: clicked on top-left square]

I probably would have used a `.map()` as the main docs suggest, but since the assignment specifically mentions *two loops*, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I also took a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx), but I have extra data I wouldn't know where to place, such as the className and keys.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem is not related to react, it's just that you declared your `n` variable before the loops, so it has always the latest value (which is 9)

Your code simulation (click any number):

```js
let n = 0
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j += 1) {
    const el = document.createElement('div')
    el.textContent = n
    el.addEventListener('click', () => handleClick(n))
    document.body.appendChild(el)
    n += 1
  }
}

function handleClick(n) {
  console.log(n)
}
```

You should calculate `n` based on `i` and `j` instead

Fixex:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j += 1) {
    const n = i * 3 + j
    const el = document.createElement('div')
    el.textContent = n
    el.addEventListener('click', () => handleClick(n))
    document.body.appendChild(el)
  }
}

function handleClick(n) {
  console.log(n)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that does solve the problem!
Although I don't understand it... I was under the impression that `n` being a primitive type, it would be passed to the functions by value and not by reference?

Comment: It is passed by value, but you don't pass it until you click the button, but at this point it's already `9`

Comment: Ah, you're right, I get it now! It's because it's an arrow function so the value is taken at the moment of calling. Thanks again!

Comment: You could also do something like `onSquareClick={(n => () => handleClick(n))(n)}` but it's not very readable

Comment: @Konrad `handleClick.bind(null, n)` would suffice if not changing the declaration of n.